# In C, tan(30) gives me a negative value! Why?

Tags: android, c, math, android-ndk, cmath

I observe that my **`tan(float)`** function from the **`cmath`** library is returning a negative value.

The following piece of code, when run :

```
    #include <cmath>
    ....

    // some calculation here gives me a value between 0.0 to 1.0.
    float tempSpeed = 0.5; 

    float tanValue = tan(tempSpeed * 60);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Log Me", "speed: %f", tanValue);
```

Gives me this result in my Log file:

```
    Log Me: speed `-6.4053311966`
```

As far as I remember

```
    tan(0.5*60) = tan(30) = 1/squareroot(3);
```

Can someone help me here as in why I am seeing a negative value? Is it related to some floating point size error? Or am I doing something really dumb?

Comment: Awesome, such quick response. Now I can go home and get some sleep. :-) Thanks guys!!

Comment: Why not look up and read `tan()` documentation?

Comment: Yeah, I Should have.. and I agree that's dumb. But, sometimes when you are deep and lost.. [like figuring out the right ways of mapping swipe length and swipe speed to the ball's trajectory], the simplest things don't occur to your head. :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In **C**, `tan` and other trigonometric functions expect *radians* as their arguments, not *degrees*. You can convert *degrees* to *radians*:

```
tan( 30. * M_PI / 180. ) == 0.57735026918962576450914878050196
```

Comment: Multiply the argument by `pi / 180` to convert from degrees to radians

Comment: Just so you know, `M_PI` isn't part of the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c

Answer (score 7):

That's the tangent of your angle (30 radians.) if you are looking for the tangent of 30 degrees, you must convert your angle to radians first.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in C the tan Function requires you to Input Radians as an argument and not The actual degree value.

so for Tan 30 , you would have to convert your 30 degrees to radian. Keep in Mind that 360 degrees is 2*Pi radian so 30 degress would be (1\6 * Pi)th of a radian.

so tan(1\6 * Pi) would give you the correct answer. where Pi is 3.142

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark .. Yup.. you are right, I seemed to have left out the 2 there.. I have corrected it now... thanks