# Python - time difference in milliseconds not working for me

Tags: python

I've read a few posts about this and thought I had some code that worked. If the difference between the 2 values is less than a 1sec then the millisecs displayed is correct.

If the difference is more than a sec, its still only showing me the difference of the millisecs.

As below.

Correct:

```
 now_wind 2013-08-25 08:43:04.776209 
 first_time_wind 2013-08-25 08:43:04.506301
 time_diff 0:00:00.269908
 diff 269
```

Wrong - this should be 2000 + 76?:

```
 now_wind 2013-08-25 08:43:25.660427
 first_time_wind 2013-08-25 08:43:23.583902
 time_diff 0:00:02.076525
 diff 76


 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import datetime
 import time
 from time import sleep
 first_time_wind = datetime.datetime.now()
 sleep (2)
 now_wind = datetime.datetime.now()
 print "now_wind", now_wind
 print "first_time_wind", first_time_wind
 time_diff_wind = (now_wind - first_time_wind)
 print "time_diff", time_diff_wind
 print "diff", time_diff_wind.microseconds / 1000
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 2, 5, 1, 879000)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 2, 5, 8, 984000)
>>> a - b
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86392, 895000)
>>> b - a
datetime.timedelta(0, 7, 105000)
>>> (b - a).microseconds
105000
>>> (b - a).seconds
7
>>> (b - a).microseconds / 1000
105
```

your microseconds don't include the seconds that have passed

Answer (score 85):

Try using total_seconds method:

```
print time_diff_wind.total_seconds() * 1000
```

That method is equivalent to: `(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6`

> Note: It's available since version 2.7

Comment: add `int(time_diff_wind.total_seconds() * 1000)` to get just the milliseconds, otherwise you will still have some decimal precision like `17215.996`

Answer (score 25):

The correct answer (in 2020) is:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta(days=1, milliseconds=50) / timedelta(milliseconds=1)
86400050.0
```

The other answers lose precision and/or are more verbose.

Comment: elegant. Same can be used for different units: `int(timedelta(days=1, milliseconds=50) / timedelta(microseconds=1))`

Answer (score 18):

I faced this issue as well, but in my case I need real milliseconds precision, so using `total_seconds() * 1000` isn't an option for me, so what I did is:

```
def millis_interval(start, end):
    """start and end are datetime instances"""
    diff = end - start
    millis = diff.days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    millis += diff.seconds * 1000
    millis += diff.microseconds / 1000
    return millis
```

I hope this helps someone else! :)

Comment: I think total_seconds() returns a floating point number and includes the microseconds, so it does retain millisecond accuracy, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Samuel This is true since Python version 2.7. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Comment: @Samuel As long as the number of total seconds was not so large that the floating point lost precision the `total_seconds()` approach should be preferred. Large is explained in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/6741942) and well exceeds a human lifetime so I couldn't think of many applications needing decimal precision.

Comment: @Samuel, but it does not keep track of longer time spans, like minutes, hours etc, so get wrong results whenever these reset to zero.

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation:

> Instance attributes (read-only):
>
> Attribute Value
>
> days  Between -999999999 and 999999999 inclusive
>
> seconds   Between 0 and 86399 inclusive
>
> microseconds  Between 0 and
>   999999 inclusive

Microseconds never exceed 999,999. Hence your milliseconds never exceed 999.