# Convert datetime object into milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

This has probably been asked like a million times, but I still didn't manage to do it.

The case is, that I need to calculate the time between two unix timestamps:

eg: 1494708797619 - 1494709197066

What I have so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.fromtimestamp(1494708797619/1000.0)
b = datetime.fromtimestamp(1494709197066/1000.0)
c = b-a
print(c)
```

But the answer is currently in datetime format like that:

```
0:06:39.447000
```

But I'd like it to be something like that:

```
399447000
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you just want the result in seconds, why are you converting to datetime at all? Why not just `1494708797619 - 1494709197066`?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18426915/1971805) will prob be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.fromtimestamp(1494708797619/1000.0)
b = datetime.fromtimestamp(1494709197066/1000.0)
c = int((b-a).total_seconds() * 1000)
print(c)
```

Will output

```
399447
```

But shortest way will be `1494708797619 - 1494709197066` as Daniel noted

Answer (score 1):

A `timedelta` object (which is what you get when you add/subtract two `datetime` or `date` objects) has a `.total_seconds()` method which returns the total seconds. Just multiply that by 1000.

```
c = b-a
c.total_seconds() * 1000
```