# Time difference in microseconds not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm trying to get difference between two datetimes, but I don't know why I'm getting 0 when trying to get microseconds:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

x = parse("2019-03-25T17:33:08.829-03:00")
y = parse("2019-03-25T18:07:08.829-03:00")

result = y - x
print(result.microseconds) // prints 0
```

Tried: 
[Python - time difference in milliseconds not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426882/python-time-difference-in-milliseconds-not-working-for-me/18426956)
and
[Python speed testing - Time Difference - milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766335/python-speed-testing-time-difference-milliseconds)

with no luck.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: there are no microseconds in those time stamps, hence zero

Comment: true subraction just give seconds change the microseconds for example `y = parse("2019-03-25T18:07:08.824-01:00")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766382) of the posts you linked says:

> Be aware that `c.microseconds` only returns the microseconds portion of the timedelta! For timing purposes always use `c.total_seconds()`.

If you want the microseconds portion, what else did you expect? The fractional part of the seconds of both your dates are equal, so the difference is 0.

Otherwise, use `result.total_seconds() * 1e6 + result.microseconds`.

Comment: @Jona It's CW, feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact, `+ result.microseconds` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You did not compute the difference in microseconds.  Rather, you found the time difference of 34 minutes, and asked for the microseconds component of that difference.  The time difference is `0:34:00`.  Of this figure, every component *except* minutes is 0.

To see this effect, insert this simple tracing code into your program:

```
print(result, type(result))
print(x, type(x))
print(y, type(y))
```

Output:

```
2019-03-25 17:33:08.829000-03:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
2019-03-25 18:07:08.829000-03:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
0:34:00 <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

You need to take the *entire* timedelta and convert it to microseconds.  Now that you see the problem, I'll bet you can fix it on your own.  :-)