# Determine smallest floating point type that can hold a string value

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion

I'm working on a method that translates a string into an appropriate `Number` type, depending upon the format of the number. If the number appears to be a floating point value, then I need to return the smallest type I can use without sacrificing precision (`Float`, `Double` or `BigDecimal`).

Based on [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java) (and other resources), I've learned than `Float` values have 23 bits for the mantissa. Based on this, I used the following method to return the bit length for a given value:

```
private static int getBitLengthOfSignificand(String integerPart,
    String fractionalPart) {
  return new BigInteger(integerPart + fractionalPart).bitLength();
}
```

If the result of this test is below 24, I return a `Float`. If below 53 I return a `Double`, otherwise a `BigDecimal`.

However, I'm confused by the result when I consider `Float.MAX_VALUE`, which is `3.4028235E38`. The bit length of the significand is 26 according to my method (where `integerPart = 3` and `fractionalPart = 4028235`. This triggers my method to return a `Double`, when clearly `Float` would suffice.

Can someone highlight the flaw in my thinking or implementation? Another idea I had was to convert the string to a `BigDecimal` and scale down using `floatValue()` and `doubleValue()`, testing for overflow (which is represented by infinite values). But that loses precision, so isn't appropriate for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tmyklebu Can you explain how that is a duplicate? I've asked a very specific question about type conversion and you appear to have linked to a generic question about inaccuracies in floating point numbers. How are the two related?

Comment: You cannot do this without "sacrificing precision."  Both in the case of `3.4028235e38 = 0xFFFFFF2A6D7FC1BEF94AD08780000000` and in various decimal cases, the way you figure out what the precision loss is is by computing a binary expansion, making this fundamentally the same question as the other one.

Answer (score 2):

The significand is stored in binary, and you can think of it as a number in its decimal representation only if you don't let it confuse you.

The exponent is a *binary* exponent that does not represent a multiplication by a power of ten but by a power of two. For this reason, the `E38` in the number you used as example is only a convenience: the real significand is in binary and should be multiplied by a power of two to obtain the actual number. Powers of two and powers of ten aren't the same, so “3.4028235” is not the real significand.
The real significand of `Float.MAX_VALUE` is in hexadecimal notation, 0x1.fffffe, and its associated exponent is 127, meaning that `Float.MAX_VALUE` is actually 0x1.fffffe * 2<sup>127</sup>.

Looking at the decimal representation to choose a binary floating-point type to put the value in, as you are trying to do, doesn't work. For one thing, the number of decimal digits that one is sure to recover from a `float` is different from the number of decimal digits one may need to write to distinguish a `float` from its neighbors (6 and 9 respectively). You chose to write “3.4028235E38” but you could have written 3.40282E38, which for your algorithm, looks easier to represent, when it isn't, really. When people write that “3.4028235E38” is the largest finite value of the `float` type, they mean that if you round this decimal number to `float`, you will arrive to the largest float. If you parse “3.4028235E38” as a double-precision number it won't even be equal to `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

To put it differently: another way to write `Float.MAX_VALUE` is `3.4028234663852885981170418348451692544E38`. It is still representable as a `float` (it represents the exact same value as `3.4028235E38`). It looks like it has many digits because these are **decimal** digits that appear for a **decimal exponent**, when in fact the number is represented internally with a binary exponent.

(By the way, your approach does not check that the exponent is in range to represent a number in the chosen type, which is another condition for a type to be able to represent the number from a string.)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed description of the underlying issues. Do you have any suggestions for a better approach to solving my problem?

Comment: @Duncan It seems to me that you are trying to translate the intention of the author of the string info a choice of format. If the author of the string wrote “0.1”, then perhaps he really only cares about this digit, and any value between 0.096 and 0.14 is acceptable to him. Then `float` is a good type to use. But perhaps the author meant “0.100000000000” and the trailing zeroes were omitted out of convention. In this case `float` is not appropriate but `double` still works.

Comment: @Duncan If this is what you are trying to do, then just do not test your function on 3.4028235E38, which is a special case: people who write this string mean exactly a certain `float` (the largest finite `float`), and this is why they write as many as 8 decimals. But they write the decimals of a representable `float`, on purpose, because the number they are translating to decimal is a `float`. It is normal for this number, with the number of decimals it has, without entering the details of its actual value, to look like it would need a `double` type to be contained accurately.

Comment: @Duncan 3.4028235E38 only **happens** to be close to one particular `float`, but another decimal representation with the same number of decimals would not have been.

Comment: Given that the input is a string, I suppose my goal is to ensure that this type of test would always pass: `assertEquals(inputString, myMethod(inputString).toString());` Is that even possible? If it is, do you have any practical advice on how to select the correct type to convert to? A naive approach might be to try successively larger types until a `toString()` test passes.

Comment: @Duncan If the goal is to have `assertEquals(inputString, myMethod(inputString).toString())`, the simplest way is to make that the test, first as `float`, then as `double`, and to use `BigDecimal` if neither binary floating-point type manages to satisfy the property. If you can afford the twice two conversions (millionth of seconds on a modern computer), this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I would work in terms of the difference between the actual value and the nearest `float`. `BigDecimal` can store any finite length decimal fraction exactly and do arithmetic on it:

Convert the `String` to the nearest `float` `x`. If `x` is infinite, but the value has a finite `double` representation use that.

Convert the `String` exactly to `BigDecimal` `y`.

If `y` is zero, use `float`, which can represent zero exactly.

If not, convert the `float` `x` to `BigDecimal`, `z`.

Calculate, in `BigDecimal` to a reasonable number of decimal places, the absolute value of `(y-z)/z`. That is the relative rounding error due to using `float`. If it is small enough for your purposes, less than some value you pick, use `float`. If not, use `double`.

If you literally want no sacrifice in precision, it is much simpler. Convert to both `float` and `double`. Compare them for equality. The comparison will be done in `double`. If they compare equal, go with the `float`. If not, go with the `double`.

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph - I presume some input values will need BigDecimal to be represented accurately. How would you propose to differentiate between those three cases?

Comment: Again, check for equality. If converting to either `float` or `double` then to `BigDecimal` gives the same numerical value as converting directly to `BigDecimal`, the float or double was exact.