# Strange Google Test failure with floating point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, googletest

I'm having some trouble testing floating point values for equality with Google Test 1.7.0.

My assertion looks like this:

```
ASSERT_NEAR(124691356.375f, actual, DELTA);
```

The test fails with the following error:

> The difference between 124691356.375f and actual is 3.625, which exceeds DELTA, where **124691356.375f evaluates to 124691360**, actual evaluates to 124691356.375, and DELTA evaluates to 0.0625.

What's going on?  `actual` and the expected result are clearly within the allowable error of 0.0625.  Why is gtest evaluating the floating point literal `124691356.375f` this way?

**Update:** `DELTA` and `actual` are of type double, and the expected value is a float literal.  If I change the literal to be a double, or change the other arguments to be floats (so that everything is of the same type) the test passes.  The question still stands - what is causing this behavior when the types don't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`124691356.375f` is a single precision floating point number, which has 7-8 significant decimal digits. So it is "rounded" to 124691360, which is not within the allowable error. You should problably use `124691356.375lf`. See also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3A_floating_point_in_modern_computers) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542944/33499).

Comment: Thanks!  The real kicker was the fact that the calculation of `actual` stored the result in a double, which has enough precision not to perform the same "rounding."

Comment: or just omit the type specifier entirely for the literal - then it will be a `double`