# Testing for upper bound violation in Java

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to use Junit to test a java program, and I'm not sure how to go about testing for upper-bound violations.

Specifically, I have written a simple program to convert between kilometers and miles.

For example, here is the method for converting from miles to kilometers

```
    public static double mileToKm(double mile){
    //1.1170347260596139E308 / 0.621371192 = Double.MAX_VALUE
    try{
        if (mile < 0 || mile > 1.1170347260596139E308){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else
            return mile / 0.621371192;}
    return 0;
}
```

So, I guess my question is two-fold: First, why is it that I can't conjure up an exception when I try

```
mileToKm(1.1170347260596139E308 + 1)
```

in junit? I assume it's a rounding issue, but if that's the case then how can I get the exception thrown?

Second, for the method to convert from km to mile, I want to throw an exception if the parameter is greater than Double.MAX_VALUE. How can I pass such a parameter? I can get the Junit test to pass if I just pass as parameter Double.MAX_VALUE * 10, but I also get a message in the Console (this is all in Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, btw) saying 'MAX = 1.7976931348623157E308'. The parameter has to be a double so it can't be BigDecimal or something like that.

OK, I lied, the question is three-fold. What's up with this:

```
double value =  Double.MAX_VALUE * 0.621371192; //max_value * conversion factor
System.out.println(value);
```

prints 1.1170347260596138E308, but then these two statements

```
System.out.println(value / 0.621371192);
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

print 1.797693134862315**5**E308 and 1.797693134862315**7**E308, respectively. In other words, I would expect these two values to both be equivalent to Double.MAX_VALUE, but the first statement has a 5 right before the E, instead of a 7. How can I fix this? Thanks so much, hope this isn't too prolix.

Comment: It would really help if you'd ask *one* question per post. But how do you expect a double to have a value that's more than `MAX_VALUE`, other than being positive infinity? If there *were* a finite value bigger than `MAX_VALUE`, that would be a more appropriate `MAX_VALUE`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you considered using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`? That would side-step some of the issues related to max values and rounding error. If you really want to deal with `double`, you could still use `BigDecimal` to do the calculation within the method, converting back to `double` for the return value (and appropriately handling the cases where the result cannot be appropriately represented as a double).

Comment: One question per post, got it. Thanks for your replies. I guess I can't really do what I thought I wanted to do here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about floating point numbers.

Firstly, the number `1.1170347260596139E308 + 1` *is not representable* using primitives in Java, as [doubles have ~16 significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java), and that addition requires 308 significant digits.

Secondly, *float/double operations are not idempotent* if you use intermediate storage (and most of the times even without it). Floating point operations *lose accuracy*, and arithmetic methods that retain accuracy over large computations (think weather models) are sought after in the scientific sector.

Thirdly, there's `Double.MAX_VALUE`, which represents the largest representable number in a primitive in Java; the only other value X such that X > `Double.MAX_VALUE` can hold is `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, and that's not a real number.

Comment: This is one of the first times I'm playing around with such large numbers, and I really DON'T understand them. Thanks a lot for the reply, it was helpful. I guess I'll go spend some time with the javadoc for Double!

Comment: It's not about large numbers; it's that floating point is fixed precision. You won't find that in the javadoc of Double - for a better intro and insight into the matter, read up the links in the [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info).