# Should I use BigDecimal or double?

Tags: java, floating-point

I have to calculate a fairly complex formula in my code, and I'm wondering how to decide whether I should use `BigDecimal` or just `double` to do it.

The function is is:

```
f(x) = 1.03^(4 - ((1/3) * (x-9)^2))
```

where `x` is a double rounded to 4 decimal points, e.g. 1.2345

what are the pros and cons of using `BigDecimal` versus `double` and how much precision might I lose if I use `double` to represent everything?

Comment: if you care about the 15th digit or so.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java

Comment: There are too many variables for there to be one specific answer.  Do you care about more than 15 significant digits precision (not 15 decimal places, 15 _total_ digits)?  If no, then `double` is probably fine as long as you recognize that many "common" numbers cannot be exactly represented as floating point.  [This is required reading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

The main pro of using **BigDecimal** over **double** is that the first one can achieve more precision over a *fixed number* of decimals. The main con is that **BigDecimal** requires more cpu operations to make same calculations.

About precision of the two, if you take the old same example of monetary value (i'm from Europe, then Euros), you can immeditely see that 0,009€ or less simply doesn't make any sense while the minimum unit is 0,01€. This is a fixed precision value and **BigDecimal** is good to manage it.

If the calculation of your question is about something that needs a sufficiently good precision (or average good precision as Jonah said) and doesn't have a well defined minimum unit, that *can* be a floating point value.

Answer (score 0):

A double can store 16 significant figures accurately on average. I don't think using a double in that formula will result in significant data loss. However, if speed is not a concern at all then using BigDecimal would be my choice. See [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)

Comment: 15.9 decimal digits at a maximum. No 'average' about it.