# DecimalFormat is not working properly

Tags: java

I am trying to apply formatting (, after 3 digits and rounding after 4 digits), using below code -

```
double a = 1231254125412512.231515235346;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
System.out.println("Number : " + formatter.format(a));
```

Above code is working properly for the number `-54125412512.231515235346` (result was `-54,125,412,512.2315`).

But it is not working for the number `-1231254125412512.231515235346` (result `-1,231,254,125,412,512.2000`).

Comment: is variable `a` float or double?

Comment: its double - double a = 1231254125412512.231515235346;

Comment: Because Double has a precision of 53 bit. So its maximum is 17 digits.
1231254125412512.231515235346 ~ 1231254125412512.2 (17 digits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you use `double` variable, and and hit max precision <strike>`Double.MIN_VALUE`</strike>.

[SOURCE:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/3850595)

> double: 64 bits (8 bytes) where **52 bits are used for the mantissa (15 to 17 decimal digits, about 16 on average**). 11 bits are used for the exponent and 1 bit is the sign bit.

To avoid this problem use `BigDecimal` instead:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("-54125412512.231515235346");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("-1231254125412512.231515235346");

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
System.out.println("Number : " + formatter.format(a));
System.out.println("Number : " + formatter.format(b));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Number : -54.125.412.512,2315
Number : -1.231.254.125.412.512,2315
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your first statement is not. 1231254125412512.231515235346 < Double.MAX_VALUE and (-1231254125412512.231515235346) > Double.MIN_VALUE. The problems is that a double doesn't have the precision to hold a number that is so large and has so much precision so it will be rounded.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt corrected and linked a source. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Double has a precision of 53 bit which is about 16 digits.