# How to simulate quantization error in theano?

Tags: python, types, theano

I want to round a tensor variable to a lower resolution representation (e.g. round a float64 value to it's float48 representation while keeping it float64). Is there an efficient way of doing this?

The closest thing I could find is the tensor.round function but I am not experienced enough to understand how to implement it. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First determine the cast of the original tensor used in theano, usually float64 or float32 which uses [23 or 52 bits to represent the mantissa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)

Then to quantize the variable by x-bits multiply by 2^(n-x), round then divide by 2^(n-x) where n is the number of bits used to represent the data in the original tensor variable.

```
if orig_tensor.type == 'float64':
    n = 52 
else:
    n = 23 

quantized_tensor = T.round(orig_tensor*(2**(n-x)))/(2**(n-x))
```