# DecimalFormat - keep all decimal numbers

Tags: java, numbers, decimalformat

I'm using DecimalFormat to format doubles into a String.
This String is then integrated into my presentation layer.

- **Problem**: I want to keep ALL decimals. *Example: "12345678.123456789"*
- **Question**: What format should I use?
- *Remark*: I use a different Locale to support multiple layouts.

**Format:** *#.##* -> This uses **ALL** numbers **BEFORE** the decimal, but **ROUNDS** the numbers **AFTER** the decimal.

I could use *#.#########* for the big decimal, but what if the decimal is even longer?

I found my small test program useful and want to share it with you.

***Can you help me to show ALL decimals?***

```
package be.softwarelab.numbers;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DecimalNumbersTest {

    private static final double NUMBER = 123456789.123456789;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String format01 = "#.";
        String format02 = "#.#";
        String format03 = "#.##";
        String format04 = "#.###";
        String format05 = "#.####"; 

        System.out.println("====== NUMBER ===== USA =====================================");
        showResult(NUMBER, format01, Locale.US);
        showResult(NUMBER, format02, Locale.US);
        showResult(NUMBER, format03, Locale.US);
        showResult(NUMBER, format04, Locale.US);
        showResult(NUMBER, format05, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("====== NUMBER ===== France ==================================");
        showResult(NUMBER, format01, Locale.FRANCE);
        showResult(NUMBER, format02, Locale.FRANCE);
        showResult(NUMBER, format03, Locale.FRANCE);
        showResult(NUMBER, format04, Locale.FRANCE);
        showResult(NUMBER, format05, Locale.FRANCE);
        System.out.println("=============================================================");
    }

    public static void showResult(double number, String format, Locale locale) {
        // Using a Locale to see the differences between regions.
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat (format, otherSymbols);

        // Create the String result
        String output = formatter.format(number);

        // Format the output for a nice presentation.
        System.out.format("    %s %11s = %20s\n", locale, format, output);
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
====== NUMBER ===== USA =====================================
en_US          #. =           123456789.
en_US         #.# =          123456789.1
en_US        #.## =         123456789.12
en_US       #.### =        123456789.123
en_US      #.#### =       123456789.1235
====== NUMBER ===== France ==================================
fr_FR          #. =           123456789,
fr_FR         #.# =          123456789,1
fr_FR        #.## =         123456789,12
fr_FR       #.### =        123456789,123
fr_FR      #.#### =       123456789,1235
=============================================================
```

**Edit:** One user mentioned a related question: [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)
This question does not solve my problems, since it focuses on limiting the size, but I need to keep it as long as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25308216/4105457) should help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I did not find my solution in this answer. This is focused on limiting the size, but I need to keep it as long as possible. My customers need to see the accuracy. I also don't need trailing zero's.

Comment: Have you investigated in the suggested answer?

Comment: "I could use #.######### for the big decimal, but what if the decimal is even longer?" => What on earth are you measuring....? and is it really accurate to 10+ decimal places? or are these values simply result of calculation using less precise numbers?

Comment: @Flown: Yes, but didn't find a solution. Have you deeper insights? Should I follow the path of the related question further? I'm diving into this other way and keep you informed.

Comment: @Adam: Maybe my accuracy is a little confusing, but I don't know exactly how to describe this. I want all decimals for the presentation layer. A measuring device show all numbers, and we want to show the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.format might help you out here - [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

```
  private static void printfWithLocale(Locale locale, Double d){
    System.out.println("Output locale: " + locale.toString());
    String simpleOutputTeplate = "simpleOutputTeplate: %s";
    String refinedOutputTeplate = "refinedOutputTeplate: %.10f";

    System.out.println(String.format(locale, simpleOutputTeplate, d));
    System.out.println(String.format(locale, refinedOutputTeplate, d));

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double d = new Double(3.1234567890123456789);

    printfWithLocale(Locale.US, d);
    System.out.println("");
    printfWithLocale(Locale.FRANCE, d);
  }
```

Code output:

```
Output locale: en_US
simpleOutputTeplate: 3.1234567890123457
refinedOutputTeplate: 3.1234567890

Output locale: fr_FR
simpleOutputTeplate: 3.1234567890123457
refinedOutputTeplate: 3,1234567890
```

You will notice that the %s (string) does not conform to the Locale, but does format the Double up to 17 decimal points.
With String.format you can further refine the way your numbers are formatted in a string.

Comment: Does this mean there's actually no way to format a double directly using the locale while keeping _all_ the decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Since double does not exactly represent some numbers, it doesn't matter if you cut to a given length of decimals (like 17). See this other question for the explanation [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)