# Wrong answer on bisection method program (C++)

Tags: c++

I am solving the typical bisection method task but with fixed tolerance `(1e-20)`, fixed interval `(0, 10)` and given function: `x^5 - a*x - 84422%100`, where user inputs `a` as a parameter.

For the example with `a = 5` I should get the answer `2.3227751229355622988` with precision `20` digits after floating point but I get `2.50000000000000000000`. Where am I wrong here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double e = 1e-20;
const int fn = 84422;

double f(int a, int x)
{
     double y = x * x * x * x * x - a * x - fn % 100;
     return (double)y;
}

int main()
{
    double lv, rv, midv, mid, root, tol;

    int left = 0;
    int right = 10;
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    do
    {
        mid = (left + right) / 2.0;
        rv = f(a, right);
        lv = f(a, left);
        midv = f(a, mid);

        if(midv == 0)
        {
             root = mid;
             break;
        }

        if(midv * lv < 0)
        {
            right = mid;
        }
        else
            left = mid;
     } while ((right - left) > e);

     root = (left + right) / 2.0;
     cout << " The Root is approximately: ";
     cout << fixed << setprecision(20) << root << endl;

     cin.get();
     cin.get();
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: you wont get 20 significant digits with doubles (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java))

Comment: @tambre 64 bits doubles dont have more significant digits, just because it is c++ not java

Answer (score 1):

Your `left` and `right` are integers.

When you assign `mid` to them, you lose significant digits (all of them virtually).

Change them to be `double`s.

Comment: i fixed them with doubles and still is not working and i get the same result

Comment: @KristianKamenov - Your `f` accepts `int`s as well. Every integer in your algorithm truncates the calculation you actually want to preform.

Comment: fixed everything to doubles and now i got answer 2.0000000000000000000

Comment: @KristianKamenov even with everything as double you wont get 20 significant digits

Comment: @KristianKamenov - Have you taken a look at the [graph of the function you calculate](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=x%5E5+-+5x+-+22)? The root is at 2.0