# How to round a big number (precision 19, scale 2) to whole integer?

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports

I want to round a big number to the nearest integer:

Ex1:`-26,687,872,856,567,000.32`, output should be:`-26,687,872,856,567,000`

Ex2:`-26,687,872,856,567,000.51`, output should be:`-26,687,872,856,567,001`

I am using this expression in jasper report:

```
Math.round($V(cost})
```

and have set `$V{cost}`, both as `java.lang.Float` and `java.lang.Double`, but I'm not getting correct results. With Float it displays `2147483647`.

Comment: Post the code that you tried along with sample input, current output and expected output.

Comment: Typo in `Math.round($V(cost})`, plus it is possible `$V(cost)` the base variable to pass `cost` can not handle the very large value you are using (64bit integer trying to fit in a 32bit?)

Comment: yeah but, I changed the Float to Double, but still I am not getting the expected output. I think Double can handle 64-bits

Comment: @Petter `-26,687,872,856,567,000.51` has 19 significant decimal digits (precision of 19).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I was trying to follow what I taught was OP's original intention. but I agre your version is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your number `-26,687,872,856,567,000.51` has 19 significant decimal digits (= precision).

- `java.long.Float` supports a [precision about 7 decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java).
- `java.long.Double` supports a [precision about 16 decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java).

Conclusion if you like to round to nearest "whole" value you need to use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Below you can can see a sample jrxml both how to round but more important how to use pattern in jasper-report. The advantage of using pattern is that you will main precision on numbers when exporting to excel and similar, still displaying only the precision you like. I'm using your number `-26,687,872,856,567,000.51` that best shows the problem `java.lang.double` have (note it is not rounding as you like, due to precision problem)

**jrxml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="bigNumber" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="597c0716-df6b-42ec-a7c8-863eb1b7174a">
    <variable name="doubleValue" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[-26687872856567000.51]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="bigDecimal" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.math.BigDecimal("-26687872856567000.51")]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <summary>
        <band height="109">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="128" height="20" uuid="9c05efb5-8b28-43e4-9e48-6dd198427bcd"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Double (Math.round()):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="128" y="0" width="302" height="20" uuid="32c78ef2-c9a3-4798-8724-bda1dc123a7a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Math.round($V{doubleValue})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="128" height="20" uuid="b9664b9f-e215-433d-a50d-29131b2bfdc3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[BigDecimal (setScale()):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="128" y="20" width="302" height="20" uuid="46fbb5a6-3f30-4b55-a353-4874b6bd72d2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{bigDecimal}.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="128" height="20" uuid="873cfaa4-68a7-49e5-9884-d7847dd9e652"/>
                <text><![CDATA[BigDecimal (format):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement x="128" y="40" width="302" height="20" uuid="8f45a367-d1cd-4699-b921-5b0d1e6abcf2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{bigDecimal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: export]

**Conclusion**

Change all your declaration's (field, variable ecc) to class `java.math.BigDecimal`

Answer (score 1):

You commented:

> I changed the Float to Double, but still I am not getting the expected output. I think Double can handle 64-bits.

There are several misconceptions here. Consult [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).

- `float`, `float8` and `double precision` are synonyms in the Postgres type system. You may be thinking of `float4` a.k.a. `real`, which occupies 4 bytes.
- `float` is an 8-byte quantity, so "64 bits" is right. But `float` is still only good for:

> **15** decimal digits precision

Bold emphasis mine.

Your attempt to store a number with a *precision* of 19 (19 significant decimal digits) is bound to fail. Try:

```
SELECT '-26687872856567777.77'::float::numeric;
```

Result:

```
-26687872856567800
```

As you can see, the number got rounded to 15 significant digits.

The **solution** is in the manual, too:

> If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary
>   amounts), use the `numeric` type instead.

Especially for numbers with more than 15 significant digits.

I can't stress this enough. Use **`numeric`**. Then your task is simple:

```
SELECT round('-26687872856567777.77'::numeric);
```

Result:

```
-26687872856567778
```

Or cast to `bigint`, the number is rounded automatically. Same result, but different data type:

```
SELECT '-26687872856567777.77'::numeric::bigint;
```

Comment: Same time, but your answer seems complementary to mine, since you address postgress, while I jasper-reports variable declaration.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Yes. :) But `float` can only represent a precision of 15 decimal digits, not 16. 2^52 = 4503599627370496, which only covers half of 9999999999999999. So 16 is wrong, strictly speaking. The answer you reference says `about 16 decimal digits` accordingly.

Comment: You mean `double`, but yes I will not argue on the exact number of decimal digits about 16 or guarantee 15 again seems complementary ;)