# MySQL JSON stores different floating point value

Tags: mysql, json, floating-point

How are floating point values in JSON data columns rounded in MySQL (5.7)?

I am having trouble finding a good resource to know how to solve my issue.

Here's what happens:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (jdoc JSON);
INSERT INTO someTable VALUES('{"data":14970.911769838869}');
```

Then select the rows:

```
SELECT * from someTable;
```

I get data back with a different final digit:
`'{"data": 14970.911769838867}'`

Any idea why this happens? Can I adjust the data in a way to prevent this or is there a rounding precision issue?

Comment: You're running into the limit of floating point precision.

Answer (score 2):

Double precision floating point has about 16 decimal digits of precision. Your number has 17 digits, so it can't be represented exactly in floating point, and you get round-off error in the last digit.

See [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)

The question is about Java, but just about everything uses the same IEEE 754 floating point format, so the answer applies pretty generally.

Comment: Ah well that explains it... seeing a floating point number and storing a floating point number don't mean the same thing when the precision limit is hit.