# Using float type or double output a decimal number in Java(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, floating-point

[image: Code]

I wanted the output to be `0.123456789123456789`. But, result is `0.123456789` in float type. `0.12345678912345678` in double type. So, I tried using `%030.19f,e` but this doesn't work either. How do I output `0.123456789123456789`?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code (properly formatted) into your question as text. A screenshot of your code is not helpful.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember that now on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `float` or `double` if you need to print exact values.

Use instead a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) that is a class to hold

> Immutable, **arbitrary-precision** signed decimal numbers

The problem using `float` and `double` is that they suffer for the rounding related to binary decimal numbers.

Comment: Thanks you. decimal numbers that i told exceed limit of float and double. I understand right?

Comment: Yes and not only. It is possible that also a relative little decimal number can't be represented with  a float (or double)

Comment: Re “ if you need to print exact values”: The difference between `double` and `BigDecimal` is not that one is exact and the other is inexact. It is that one is binary and fixed precision and the other is decimal and variable precision. `BigDecimal` can represent decimal numerals exactly, but it cannot represent other numbers exactly. For example, it does not represent one-third exactly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you are right. But here we are talking about decimal numbers.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO: Are you sure OP is going to do nothing other than read and write numbers, perhaps do a little addition or simple multiplication? Because if they do almost any other arithmetic, they will get rounding errors, which they will not expect because you have told them `BigDecimal` is exact.

Comment: @EricPostpischil using BigDecimal you have full control over the rounding due to math operations. So is you that decide how the result is rounded after an operation choosing the precision, scale and rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

For bigger numbers you can use BigDecimal. For example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    BigDecimal bdcm=new BigDecimal("0.123456789123456789");
    System.out.println(bdcm);
    BigDecimal bdcm2=new BigDecimal("100.123456789123456789");
    System.out.println(bdcm.add(bdcm2));
 }
}
```

And the output is proper :)