# Parsing double in gradle is giving unexpected values

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, precision

I've written a task in gradle which increments my projects version number when a jar file is created.

I'm using a simple decimal version number with 3 decimal places for example: `version '2.001'`.

The code works by parsing the string value to a double, incrementing by 0.001 and replacing the string. When incrementing from a non-zero ended value, the code works fine. for example `2.001` is correctly increased to `2.002`. But when I try to parse a zero ended value, for example `2.010`, I get a weird error. When the value `2.010` is parsed in as a double by `Double.parseDouble`, the value is read as `2.010999999999999997`.

The full code is below:

```
task increaseVersionCode {
  double versionCode = Double.parseDouble(version.toString())

  println versionCode
  versionCode += 0.001
  println versionCode
  println "version '$version'"
  println "version '" + versionCode + "'"

  String newBuildFile = buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version '$version'","version '" + versionCode + "'")

  buildFile.setText(newBuildFile)
}
```

The result of the `println` when the version is `version '2.010'` is below:

```
2.0109999999999997
2.0119999999999996
version '2.0109999999999997'
version '2.0119999999999996'
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the explanation, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542957/2003986) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/2003986) too, it's all about internal representation.

For the solution, use `BigDecimal`

```
double a = 2.010 + 0.001;
System.out.println(a); 

BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.010);
System.out.println(b.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.001)));
```

Output :

```
2.0109999999999997
2.011
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a great help