# C program is giving unexpected answer

Tags: c, floating-point, string-formatting, truncate

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float a;

    scanf("%f",&a);
    a=(int)(a*1000+0.5);
    printf("%.5f\n",a);
    a=a/1000;
    printf("%.5f\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

This program is written to round off a floating point number up to 3 decimal points in a specific way; e.g. `65.43296` should print as `65.43200`, not `65.432`.

According to logic it should work but I am getting an unexpected answer like following:

```
1234.56789        
1234568.00000    
1234.567993
```

Explain this behaviour.

Comment: `float` doesn't have very much precision.

Comment: you could change a from float to double, and then change your format specifiers from `%f` to `%lf`, but you still might have rounding errors for some values due to the way floating point numbers are represented.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this related question: [How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java). The question discusses Java, but the same logic applies to C.

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html); and [Originalpdf](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Comment: Also related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although input was `"1234.56789"`, that is only *near* the value saved in `float a`.

`float` as 32-bit object, can only store *exactly* about 2<sup>32</sup> different values. Due to the [typical binary encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) of a `float`, 1234.56789 is not one of those 2<sup>32</sup>.  Instead the nearest float is used.

```
1234.56787109375   // nearest float's exact value
1234.56789
1234.5679931640625 // next nearest float's exact value
```

`a*1000+0.5` can be expected to result in 1234568.375 and `(int)(a*1000+0.5)` to 1234568.0.  So far no great surprise.

The quotient `a/1000;` is also a `float` and since it too is not one of those 2<sup>32</sup>, the result is  the nearest `float`

```
1234.5679931640625 // nearest float.
1234.568           // math result of 1234568.0/1000
1234.568115234375  // next nearest float
```

`printf("%.5f\n", 1234.5679931640625)` is then as seen by OP.

```
1234.56799
```

In general, `float` will provide expected answers when the number of leading significant digits if 6 or less.  OP's expectation of `"1234.56800"` is 9 digits.

---

Had code used `double`, similar unexpected answers can occur when the number of leading significant digits exceeds 15.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the inconsistency in your problem is the number of decimal places the `float` type works on. It has a simple precision range of `3.4 E-38 to 3.4E+38` (has 4 bytes). In case you should use the `double` has range of `1.7 E-308 to 1.7E+308` however takes up more memory (8 bytes).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double a;

    scanf("%lf",&a);
    a=(int)(a*1000+0.5);
    printf("%.5f\n",a);
    a=a/1000;
    printf("%.5lf\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```