# Python3 and C different math division result

Tags: python, c

I have a simple  number division. I have this two number:

- 39.654
- 8.381903173E-8

So, if I do the division on C:

```
// ...
float ii = 39.654;
double bb = 8.381903173E-8;
printf("\n%.20f\n", ii/bb);
// ...
```

The output is: `473090639.56200009584426879883`

But, if I work on Python3:

```
39.654/8.381903173E-8
```

The output is: `473090647.5719557`

If I use a calculator, indeed, the true value is that of Python3

What is wrong with my C code?

Thanks!
Regards!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java

Comment: [Single-precision values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can only represent so many places before they break down. You're at the limit here with values >1e9 where there will be a lot of approximation beyond ~8 places as there's only 23 bits to represent the actual numerical part. Only use `float` if you want to sacrifice accuracy in order to boost performance, something often imperative when doing real-time 3D math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must compare apples to apples. In Python, all floating-point variables are of type `double`, so you should use the same data type in your C program:

```
double ii = 39.654;
double bb = 8.381903173E-8;
printf("\n%.20f\n", ii/bb);
```

Comment: Consider `ii` as `float` and `bb` as `double`. When we do `ii/bb` shouldn't the `ii` be promoted to double for this operation?

Comment: @dodobhoot It will be promoted. But its original accuracy (and value) will be that of a `float`.

Comment: @EmmanuelArias after making that correction the program outputs `473090647.57195568084716796875` which agrees with Python. BTW didn't you get a compiler warning: *'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'* ?

Comment: holy... yeah! my problem was that! I tried  to compare apples with cars. I think that this is the problem about use Python from some time ago. @WeatherVane I did not get any warning.