# Is this a good hashing function for short strings?

Tags: c++, string, hash

For strings of 10-50 characters:

```
double hash(const std::string & str)
{
    double result = 0;
    int n=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        result += (str[i] - '@')*pow(256.0,i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

can this be used in a production code?

- increasing total throughput of hashing when used with std::hash by ILP
- correctness/uniqueness
- scalability

new version by comments:

```
double hash(const std::string & str)
{
    double result = 0;
    int n=str.length();

    // maybe using multiple adders to do concurrently multiple chars
    // since they are not dependent
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        result += lookupCharDoubleType[str[i]]*lookupPow[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

another version by another comment:

```
double hash(const std::string & str)
{
    double result = 0;
    int n=str.length();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        result = result * 256.0 + lookupCharDoubleType[str[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why you do not use buildin one?

Comment: You normally want a hash to be an integer.

Comment: What if it will be only used for uniqueness? Not for indexing or something? And if I'm trying some algorithms to learn?

Comment: There must be some reason that everyone uses prime number multipliers in hashes, don't you think?

Comment: Unless you have some sort of performance bottleneck just use `std::hash`.  If you just want to check if two values are equal or not just use `operator ==`

Comment: If you're going to use `pow`, don't -- there is no need to.  Just use a table of precomputed powers of 256 and do a lookup using `i` as the index.

Comment: Also, 256 ^ 50 is going to be a huge number and wont be representable as a 64bit integer, which due to floating point inaccuracy, you should be using for the hash value.

Comment: @NathanOliver can std::hash be used by instruction level parallelism with this function to increase total throughput of hashing using integer+fp pipelines together?

Comment: If you're going to use values, precompute them.  In a strange way, you're defeating the purpose of the hash by using non-hashing techniques (like computing the same value over and over again instead of a table lookup).

Comment: well, the lookup may not be necessary since you can use `result = result*256+(str[i] - '@')` (to some degree)

Comment: I think my answer shows that this question is *not* "primarily opinion-based" and can be answered objectively. We should reopen it. Given the purpose of a hash function and the OP's stated goal of determining uniqueness, we can say without doubt that the function in question is not a good choice. Also: this is an honest question that provides enough information to answer it, including code. I don't think it deserves all those downvotes.

Comment: Compute an md5 / sha1 / sha256 and then sum the digest bytes into an `unsigned int` (letting it wrap)?

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting either.  Comments were given as to how to improve the function in terms of time taken, and answers were given as to why it is not a good hash for uniqueness.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb. If you are not an expert in Cryptogrophy or Hashing don't write your own Crypt / Hash code. These are exceedingly specialized fields and getting it correct (or even close to good) is very difficult (and proving it is good is even harder).

Comment: @MartinYork can we use genetic algorithm to produce one? Maybe by giving parameters as functions(such as modulo or multiplication)and variables (ordinary numbers) and expect it to minimize hash collisions and evolve those ordinary numbers automatically to magical numbers?

Comment: Why not find some already written algorithms for hashing. They will generally have an analysis on how good they are in terms of collisions and speed. You will trade usually trade one for the other. `std::hash` is your best option.

Comment: @MartinYork thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a good hashing function for short strings?

**No, it's not a good hash for uniqueness.** You're basically mapping the string onto a `double`. For a string that's 50 characters long, you're going to get a value on the order of `256 ^^ 50`, which is 2.58e120. That's well within a double's *range*, which is 1.7e308, but you have to understand that `double` doesn't represent numbers exactly -- it's only 8 bytes long after all.

Your code maps a string to a `double` as if the characters were base-256 digits, with the first character being the least significant digit:

The string `hello` maps like this:

```
'h' * 256^^0 + 'e'*256^^1 + 'l' * 256^^2 + 'l' * 256^^3 + 'o' * 256^^4
```

For a string larger than a few bytes, the last characters will be by far the most significant part of the result, and all the other characters will get dropped entirely because a `double` doesn't have the precision to represent all those bits.

**The end result is that your hash function will only consider the last few characters.** A good hash function should change whenever *any* of the characters in the string change, so that strings that are similar but not exactly the same are extremely unlikely to have the same hash value. With your function, hash values are likely to be the same as long as the last several characters are the same.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, folks, I hit the submit button well before I was done answering.

Comment: FWIW, in those cases, delete the answer, edit the rest in, and then undelete.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/643383), a double has 53 bits of precision. 53/8=6.625, so only about the last 6 and a half characters in your string will matter.  But don't let me stop you -- you'll learn a lot more if you actually try it. Build a simple version of your function (don't worry about the lookup tables etc) and try hashing different equal-length strings where the last 8 or 10 characters are the same.

Comment: Another option is to quickly edit the answer you accidentally posted and add <<editing>>, save, then do your edit.