# How come Java handle floating-point-imprecision so strange?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

After a small discussion with some fellow programmers about floating-point-imprecision we found that Java has some behaviour that is very strange to us.

```
System.out.println(0.1 + 0.2); // 0.30000000000000004
System.out.println((float) 0.1 + (float) 0.2); // 0.3
```

For some reason, when you cast the variables to a float, the inacuraccy disappears?  We've tried to look into some explanations, but couldn't find any.

Does anyone have a clue why Java behaves this way?

Note: I know what floating-point imprecision is, just not why it disappears when I cast to floats. I know the different in precision issue in play here.

Comment: That's a different question and has no relation to this behaviour. I know why they are inaccurate, just not why they disappear if you cast  them. @SirE_net4theDownvoter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java’s default formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54871593/298225) produces just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the floating-point number from neighboring floating-point numbers.

When the source text `0.3` is converted to `double`, the result is the closest `double` value, which is 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. When this is printed, “0.3” suffices to uniquely identify it, because 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 is of course the closest value, since that is how we got it from `0.3` in the first place.

The source texts `0.1` and `0.2` produce 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 and
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. When these are added in `double` format, the result is 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125. Note this is different from the number above. So, when it is printed, “0.3” does not suffice to distinguish it from the neighboring value 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. It is necessary to produce “0.30000000000000004” to show that it is different.

When the value is converted to `float`, formatting for `float` is used, instead of formatting for `double`. When formatting for `float`, only values representable in `float` are candidates for what are neighbors. The value representable in `float` that is nearest 0.3 is 0.300000011920928955078125. This is also the result of `(float) 0.1 + (float) 0.2`, and it is sufficiently distinguished from the neighboring `float` values (0.2999999821186065673828125 and 0.3000000417232513427734375) by printing merely “0.3”.