# Why do C and Java round floats differently?

Tags: java, c, floating-point, printf

Consider the floating point number 0.644696875. Let's convert it to a string with eight decimals using Java and C:

## Java

```java
import java.lang.Math;
public class RoundExample{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(String.format("%10.8f",0.644696875));
     }
}
```

result: 0.6446968**8**

try it yourself: http://tpcg.io/oszC0w

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%10.8f", 0.644696875); //double to string
    return 0;
}
```

result: 0.6446968**7**

try it yourself: http://tpcg.io/fQqSRF

## The Question

Why is the last digit different?

## Background

The number 0.644696875 cannot be represented exactly as a machine number. It is represented as the fraction 2903456606016923 / 4503599627370496 which has a value of 0.6446968749999999

This is admittedly an edge case. But I am really curious as to the source of the difference.

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204359/is-numberform-double-rounding-numbers

Comment: Please note that the issue probably has nothing to do with the binary representation but the way the `printf` function works in each language.

Comment: The default rounding behaviour is a somewhat arbitrary choice. Java [seems to use banker's rounding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), the GNU libc [seems to round to the nearest integer by default](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html).

Comment: @millimoose you are referring of course to the string representation right?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - Java doesn't do rounding elsewhere in this case, the CPU rounds the actual floating point representation.

Comment: Also emphasis on "seems to" because I found two contradictory statements about Java and I don't think the behaviour above is banker's rounding?

Comment: The point is: Java will work with the value with the minimum number of digits, that will **uniquely identify** this value. This is `0.644696875`, which will be rounded up to `0.64469688`. In contrast, C will work with the exact double value, which is about `0.64469687499999999997363220316515253....`; this is rounded _down_ to `0.64469687`

Comment: @Ctx so it follows then that C is more accurate than Java because it uses the exact double value?

Comment: @gdelfino No. The value is the same underneath unless something truly bizarre is happening.

Comment: @Ctx - what, no, none of what you said is correct. Both Java and C use an uhh 52-bit integer multiplied by 2 to the power of an 11-bit integer exponent. Decimal digits only appear when this representation is converted to a string for humans to use, unless you're using some arbitrary-precision class there are no decimal digits involved internally.

Comment: @millimoose: CPUs generally do not have instructions to convert strings like “0.644696875” to floating-point. Java has to do that with its own subroutines. Furthermore, Java’s behavior is tightly specified so that the same results are produced on different platforms—each implementation must ensure it operates in the required way, regardless of whether it uses a single CPU instruction to do that or uses complicated subroutines.

Comment: @Ctx: Yes, a C implementation that uses round-to-nearest (the C standard is looser than the Java standard and does not require this) is more accurate than a Java implementation because, per my answer below, Java requires **two** rounding operations while formatting, and and this increases error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Conclusion

The Java specification requires a troublesome double rounding in this situation. The number 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875 is first converted to 0.644696875 and then rounded to 0.64469688.

In contrast, the C implementation simply rounds 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875 directly to eight digits, producing 0.64469687.

### Preliminaries

For `Double`, Java uses IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point. In this format, the value nearest the number in the source text, 0.644696875, is 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875, and I believe this is the actual value to be formatted with `String.format("%10.8f",0.644696875)`.<sup>1</sup>

### What the Java Specification Says

[The documentation for formatting with the `Double` type and `f` format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec) says:

> … If the precision is less than the number of digits which would appear after the decimal point in the string returned by `Float.toString(float)` or `Double.toString(double)` respectively, then the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm. Otherwise, zeros may be appended to reach the precision…

Let’s consider “the string returned by … `Double.toString(double)`”. For the number 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875, this string is “0.644696875”. This is because the Java specification says that [`toString` produces just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the number within the set of `Double` values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54871593/298225), and “0.644696875” has just enough digits in this case.<sup>2</sup>

That number has nine digits after the decimal point, and `"%10.8f"` requests eight, so the passage quoted above says “the value” is rounded. Which value does it mean—the actual operand of `format`, which is 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875, or that string it mentions, “0.644696875”? Since the latter is not a numeric value, I would have expected “the value” to mean the former. However, the second sentence says “Otherwise [that is, if more digits are requested], zeros may be appended…” If we were using the actual operand of `format`, we would show its digits, not use zeros. But, if we take the string as a numeric value, its decimal representation would have only zeros after the digits shown in it. So it seems this is the interpretation intended, and Java implementations appear to conform to that.

So, to format this number with `"%10.8f"`, we first convert it to 0.644696875 and then round it using the round half up rule, which produces 0.64469688.

This is a bad specification because:

- It requires two roundings, which can increase the error.
- The roundings occur in hard-to-predict and hard-to-control places. Some values will be rounded after two decimal places. Some will be rounded after 13. A program cannot easily predict this or adjust for it.

(Also, it is a shame they wrote zeros “may be” appended. Why not “Otherwise, zeros **are** appended to reach the precision”? With “may”, it seems like they are giving the implementation a choice, although I suspect they meant the “may” is predicated on whether zeros are needed to reach the precision, not on whether the implementor chooses to append them.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> When `0.644696875` in the source text is converted to `Double`, I believe the result should be the nearest value representable in the `Double` format. (I have not located this in the Java documentation, but it fits the Java philosophy of requiring implementations to behave identically, and I suspect the conversion is done in accordance with `Double.valueOf(String s)`, which [does require this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).) The nearest `Double` to 0.644696875 is 0.6446968749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875.

<sup>2</sup> With fewer digits, the seven-digit 0.64469687 is insufficient because the `Double` value closest to it is 0.6446968**699999999774519210404832847416400909423828125**. So eight digits are needed to uniquely distinguish 0.6446968**749999999470645661858725361526012420654296875**.

Comment: What about "shall be"? That's more on terms with the standard-writing nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

Likely what's happening here is they're using slightly different methods for converting the number to a string, which introduces a rounding error.  It's also possible that the method by which the string is converted to a float during compilation is different between them, which again, can give slightly different values due to rounding.

Remember though, float has 24 bits of accuracy for its fraction, which comes out to ~7.22 decimal digits [log10(2)*24], and the first 7 digits agree between them, so it's just the last few least significant bits that are different.

Welcome to the fun world of Floating Point Math, where 2+2 does not always equal 4.

Comment: What's .22 of a decimal digit?

Comment: @JL2210 In floating-point terms a very inaccurate representation that will flap between ~2.2 different values instead of the normal 10, or in other words, it's only 22% accurate, not 100%.

Comment: There is no `float` (32-bit binary floating-point) involved. If there were, the value would be 0.644696891307830810546875, and we would see “0.64469689”—ending in 9, not 8 or 7.

Comment: 2+2 is always 4 in all the floating-point formats used by Java. Adding two values that are not exactly two may sometimes not produce exactly 4, but this applies to most numerical systems. If you see two possibilities but they are both at the level of superstition, it's fine not to answer (in fact, Java's conversion to decimal is different from that of most C compilers(1), and the conversion from decimal is identical to that of most C compilers(1)).

Comment: (1) most C compilers including the one on tpcg.io