# Would stringify an already rounded float number and then convert it back to number create further precision error?

Tags: javascript, string, floating-point, stringify

Accrodading to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), I know 0.1+0.2 results in 0.30000000000000004 instead of 0.3 because of floating point errors. However, what if I copy "0.30000000000000004" from alert(0.1+0.2) and write Number("0.30000000000000004"), would it still equal to 0.1+0.2?

Or in general:

```
let a=float_number_1 + float_number2;
let b=Number((float_number_1 + float_number2).toString());
```

Does a always exactly equal to b?

Comment: `console.log(Number("0.30000000000000004") === 0.1+0.2)`

Comment: For the cases you think of, yes. The only case that comes to mind, where this fails, is `NaN !== Number("NaN")`.

Comment: @epascarello—I think the OP is looking at the general case, not that special case.

Comment: Seems like a simple, albeit time-consuming, thing to test.

Comment: Btw depending on how you define "equal", `-0` should be the only other edge case (`-0 === 0`, and `NaN !== NaN`, but `Object.is(-0, 0) === false`, and `Object.is(NaN, NaN) === true`). I could go into details about how conversion from number to string and back works, but it's late, i am tired, and the spec has a nice note about this: "If x is any Number value other than -0, then ToNumber(ToString(x)) is exactly the same Number value as x.", in the notes below [Number::toString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring). Note, that being tired, i can always make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

[Java’s default conversion of a number to a string is specified to produce enough digits to **uniquely distinguish** the number from adjacent representable values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54871593/298225) In other words, it is deliberately designed to produce a string that can be converted back to a number to produce the original value.

So, if you convert from a `float` to a string to a `float` or from a `double` to a string to a `double`, you will get the original number. If you convert a `double` to a string to a `float`, you may get a different number.