# running the method for large numbers gives an inaccurate result

Tags: java

I have such a method

```
    public double count(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

for arguments: "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 + 1"
Expected:
111111111111111111111111111111111111111112
Real output:
1.1111111111111112E41

how to change it?

```
public BigDecimal count(double a, double b) {
    BigDecimal x= BigDecimal.valueOf(a);
    BigDecimal y= BigDecimal.valueOf(b);
    return x.add(y);

}
```

and for this Real output:111111111111111120000000000000000000000001.0 wtf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print a double value without scientific notation using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java)

Comment: java `double` has about 16 significant decimal digits https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/2711811 - you would also find `a == count(a,1)` for your example argument.  To change? see `BigDecimal`.

Comment: For your `BigDecimal` example - you are missing the point - when you initialize the double to what you think is a sequence of 41 1s - it is losing the signficant digits (not the magnitude) down to ~16.  Your best constructing a BigDecimal from a string in your case.

Comment: thx Andy 1234567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments the `double` has only ~16 significant decimal digits of precision ( see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543600/2711811 ).  So this leads to this incongruity:

```
// 25 1's
double a = 1111111111111111111111111.;
double b = 100;
double c = (a + b);
System.out.println((a == c));  // true
```

In your example you're better off using `BigDecimal`.  Here's an example:

```
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.5");
 System.out.println(bd);
 bd = bd.add(new BigDecimal(1));
 System.out.println(bd);
```

prints:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.5
111111111111111111111111111111111111111112.5
```

And going back to double loses the precision:

```
System.out.println(bd.doubleValue());
```

prints:

```
1.1111111111111112E41
```

Also, if you are only working with integers then `BigInteger` would suffice.