# How print Double value exactly as it was assigned?

Tags: java, double, decimal, precision

Following code prints `12113411122222,545000`:

```
Double value = 12113411122222.545421d;
System.out.println(String.format("%f", value));
```

How to make exact value that the variable `value` was assigned to to be printed - `12113411122222.545421`?

**Update:** I should have said this at the beginning - I know that `BigDecimal` needs to be used when precision is needed. However I am using a library which reads a certain type of file and outcome of that is that I get a bunch of attributes from that file. One of the attributes is passed to me from the 3rd party library as a double. After that I am sending attribute value to database which results in attribute value being saved as `1.2113411122222545E13` because value is being converted to `String`. So now I am looking for a solution how to 'lose' exponent part and making assumption: if `Double.MAX_VALUE` is `1.7976931348623157E308` then it means I might get attribute value with lots of decimal numbers, for example `12113411122222.545421121212212d`, and how do I convert that `Double` to `String` without 'loosing' any numbers. I suspect this is an issue with `Double`'s precision but it is counter-intuitive because `Double.MAX_VALUE` is `1.7976931348623157E308`. I guess a better knowledge of inner works of Java and numbers in computer systems in general is need to understand the issue.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` instead. `double`s are inherently imprecise.

Comment: 64bit double does not have the range for that, they can be used basically up to 15 digits. You need another datatype if you want to have such big precision.

Comment: You can't. `double` does not have enough precision to represent the number you assigned.

Comment: Java Double is a floating point type with a limited precision. If you have too many significant digits you will loose some information and Double starts rounding. Use BigDecimal for better precision. Or if you just transport values, without doing math, consider using String instead of Double.

Comment: You can't avoid this, and indeed this would be a source of bugs if you were relying on it being precisely represented. Such a floating point literal is flagged as a problem [in Google's error prone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/FloatingPointLiteralPrecision), for example.

Comment: After your edit, we had [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146241/how-to-check-if-float-is-being-truncated-by-float-parsefloat-from-string) last week. Check it out.

Comment: You can easily convert a double to a String without problems or "losing digits." The problem is that you've already lost the precision by converting it from a String to a double.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong datatype. With a double you can‘t store that much numbers after the decimal separator. You should go for a `BigDecimal`
edit:

```
String number = "12113411122222.545421";
BigDecimal value = new  BigDecimal(number);
System.out.println(String.format("%f", value));
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have fixed it. This should compile...

Comment: Yep, it now compiles but it gives the wrong result. You should pass a string, not a double for it to work.

Comment: Ok than we got our Solution. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Sry I have a Qwertz/German Keyboard layout. I only can make „“ not “ “.

Comment: You mean Shift+2 does not make `"`?

Comment: I am aware that I could use `BigDecimal` constructor with `String` but after I have updated my question you should now see that this won't help me:)

Comment: Which library are u using right now? Maybe this can help us answering your question.