# How to access the decimal numbers which are not stored in float value

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

If I want to access the 100th decimal of the number 1/919, is there a way to do so?
I know that floating values are stored only upto certain decimals so I can access only the decimals which are stored but how to access the decimals which are not stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Python stores floats as 64-bit floating point values, which [don't have the precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-do-floats-and-doubles-have-in-java) to go out to 100 decimals. You will have to use the `decimal` package and set the precision to what you need.

```py
import decimal

# calculate up to 120 decimals
decimal.get_context().prec = 120

result = decimal.Decimal(1) / decimal.Decimal(919)
print(result)


# pull an arbitrary digit out of the string representation of the result
def get_decimal_digit(num, index):
    # find where the decimal points start
    point = str(num).rfind('.')
    return int(str(num)[index + point + 1])

# get the 100th decimal
print(get_decimal_digit(result, 100))
```

Comment: So if I want to say access the millionth digit, I can do so? Won't this store large amount of data?

Comment: You can if you change the precision. `decimal` uses the same idea as IEEE 754 floats of a base, sign, and exponent, they just support arbitrary precision unlike IEEE 754. So to extract the n-th digit you still have to go through the same conversion that `str()` runs.