# Why strlen doesn't work in a paticular digit

Tags: php, strlen

I made this function. It seemed it's working but when it comes to 20 digits number, the return value was 19. I'm wondering why this problem happen..

My function

```
function sumDigits($n) {
    return strlen($n);
}

echo sumDigits(100);  //3
echo sumDigits(1000);  //4
echo sumDigits(12345);  //5
echo sumDigits(1000000000);  //10
echo sumDigits(145874589632);  //12
echo sumDigits(0);  //1
echo sumDigits(12345698745254856320);  //19  <-- Why not 20?
```

Can you please somebody explain for me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for my last reply, I've just come back from work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would point out that the name of your function is misleading, as you are not really summing the values of the digits, but are *counting* the digits. So I would call your function `countDigits` instead of `sumDigits`.

The reason why it doesn't work for large numbers, is that the string representation will switch to scientific notation, so you're actually getting the length of "1.2345698745255E+19" not of "12345698745254856320"

If you are only interested in integers, you will get better results with the logarithm:

```
function countDigits($n) {
    return ceil(log10($n));
}
```

For numbers that have decimals, there is no good solution, since the precision of 64-bit floating pointing point numbers is limited [to about 16 significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-do-floats-and-doubles-have-in-java), so even if you provide more digits, the trailing decimals will be dropped -- this has nothing to do with your function, but with the precision of the number itself. For instance, you'll find that these two literals are equal:

```
if (1.123456789123456789123456789 == 1.12345678912345678) echo "equal";
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice about naming and detailed explanation. I didn't know that the string representation switches to scientific notation, I'm glad to know that. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you function parameter is an integer, exceeding the limit.
If you dump it, it actually shows the following:
`1.2345698745255E+19` - which is 19 letters.

If you would do the following, it will return 20 - mind the quotes, which declares the input as string.

`echo sumDigits("12345698745254856320");  //19  <-- Why not 20? -> now will be 20`

Comment: I see. Thank you for your helpful explanation and an example! It helped me to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://php.net/strlen), `strlen()` expects a string so a cast happens. With default settings you get `1.2345698745255E+19`:

```
var_dump((string)12345698745254856320);
```

```
string(19) "1.2345698745255E+19"
```

The root issue is that PHP converts your integer literal to float because it exceeds `PHP_INT_MAX` so it cannot be represented as integer:

```
var_dump(12345698745254856320, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

In 64-bit PHP:

```
float(1.2345698745254857E+19)
int(9223372036854775807)
```

You could change display settings to avoid `E` notation but you've already lost precision at this point.

Computer languages that store integers as a fixed amount of bytes do not allow arbitrary precision. Your best chance is to switch to strings:

```
var_dump('12345698745254856320', strlen('12345698745254856320'));
```

```
string(20) "12345698745254856320"
int(20)
```

... and optionally use an arbitrary precision library such as [BCMath](https://php.net/bcmath) or [GMP](https://php.net/gmp) if you need actual maths.

It's also important to consider that this kind of issues is sometimes a symptom that your input data is not really meant to be an integer but just a very long digit-only string.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I was just trying to solve a questions on Edabit and I got this issue. It was good I asked here as you guys' answers were informative and made me realise what I need to learn about. Thanks a lot!