# Constexpr Math Functions

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, cmath

So noticed from this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) that none of the math functions in c++11 seems to make use of constexpr, whereas I believe all of them could be. So that leaves me with two questions, one is why did they choose not to make the functions constexpr. And two for a function like `sqrt` I could probably write my own constexpr, but something like sin or cos would be trickier so is there a way around it.

Comment: They didn't choose not to make the functions constexpr. They just didn't make any choice (I believe there are proposals to make them so in the future).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - there's some discussion, but the problem with making complicated functions `constexpr` is that the compiler then has to do what would otherwise be a runtime computation, and that means having a C++ interpreter built in to the compiler. It's a big job...

Comment: @PeteBecker not all of them are complex, but I guess by saying that I'm also saying why not just do them on my own

Comment: So what should the compiler set the value of `v` for `constexpr double v = tan(1.570796326)`?

Comment: Note, [gcc has implemented most of the math function as constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27744079/1708801) although the extension is non-conforming this should change. So definitely doable.

Comment: I think one has to distinguish here: It seems almost impossible to implement the math functions *efficiently* as `constexpr` functions *in pure C++*.  At least given the restrictions on `constexpr` functions in C++11.  On the other hand, the math functions are a very well-known finite set of functions that a compiler could easily provide as builtins and evaluate at compile-time.  This mixing of core language features and library functions might be considered ugly, but also worth the thing.  Also see [Alisdair Meredith's talk on CppCon 2014](http://youtu.be/fBU1R7jp_TE?t=31m51s).

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps of course, to `1258025171.80666637420654296875`, if `double` is the IEEE 754 `binary64`.

Comment: See [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1383r0.pdf) for a proposal of adding more constexpr <cmath> to the C++ standard.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Actually, because of old and annoying legacy, almost none of the math functions can be `constexpr`, since they all have the side-effect of setting `errno` on various error conditions, usually domain errors.

Comment: So is there any way to get around this short of doing my own functions

Comment: No. That is, I don't think there's a library of constexpr math functions already available, so not even that would work. (Of course, C++14 will make implementing them much more convenient and efficient.)

Comment: @aaronman The [post-Bristol mailing](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/post-bristol-standards-papers-mailing-available) is a good place to start (the list of papers discussed during the April meeting in Bristol).

Comment: A function can be constexpr and still sometimes throw, etc. The value of a sum of double may depend on a rounding mode, but accommodations are made for the constexpr case. `errno` is really not a good reason.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Throwing and `errno` are two very different beasts. The C standard math functions are specified to modify `errno`, not throw an exception. So I don't understand your point.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Addition is specified to set FE_INEXACT if the result is not exact. However, an addition is still allowed to be constexpr. Does this look closer to the `errno` situation to you?

Comment: It comes close, except that nowhere in C99 can I find such a specification, much less in C++11. The closest is there reference to the ISO 60559 operations in Annex F of C99. However, C++ only references the library clauses of C, so this annex has no normative role in C++. I don't think C++ has any requirement that addition has side effects. Note in particular the lack of any "contracted" floating point operations in C++11 section 5 intro, which are there in the equivalent section of C99.

Answer (score 8):

From "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)", by B. Stroustrup, describing C++11:

> *"To be evaluated at compile time, a function must be suitably simple: a constexpr function must consist of a single return-statement; no loops, and no local variables are allowed. Also, a constexpr function may not have side effects."*

Which means that it must be inline, without for, while and if statements and local variables. Side effects are also forbidden (ex: changing of errno). Another problem is that most of math functions are FPU instructions which are not represented in pure c/c++ (they are written in assembler code). That's why non of cmath function is declared as constexpr.

Comment: This is not true anymore in C++14.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I gave the answer why those functions can't be constexpr in c++11, because question was about c++11.

Comment: The other answer already stated that `errno` was the main reason, not really sure if your answer adds any other important information

Comment: @aaronman, as Marc Glisse said, errno is not a good reason because c++ standard could provide a parallel implementation of those functions which would not modify errno. But even then constexpr implementation would'n be possible without some intrinsic compiler feature. I don't want to argue, but I think, I pointed several good reasons for that. I may be wrong of course. I'm currently writing a library which would gain a lot from constexpr math functions - that's why I'm here - but I think that there are much more problems than just 'errno'.

Comment: @AdamSzaj constexpr functions (even c++11 ones) are turing complete, so I don't see the issue you are bringing up, here is an example of [contexpr sqrt](https://github.com/aaronjosephs/constexpr/blob/master/constexprsqrt.cpp) I wrote a while back

Comment: Quite nice, but try `awsome::sqrt(3e13)` . Have you tried to implement sin, cos, tanh, or similar functions? I know that there are algorithms for such functions, but do you think that `constexpr_sin(x) == sin(x)`?

Answer (score 6):

> So noticed from this page that none of the math functions in c++11
>   seems to make use of constexpr, whereas I believe all of them could
>   be. So that leaves me with two questions, one is why did they choose
>   not to make the functions constexpr.

This part is very well answered by *Sebastian Redl* and *Adam Szaj* so won't be adding anything to it.

> And two for a function like sqrt I could probably write my own
>   constexpr, but something like sin or cos would be trickier so is there
>   away around it.

Yes, you can write your own version of constexpr sin, cos by using the taylor series expansions of these functions. Have a look at this super cool github repo which implements several mathematical functions as constexpr functions [Morwenn/static_math](https://github.com/Morwenn/static_math)

Comment: Not so super cool: try calculating `smath::cos(20.)`. Cosine greater than 3... It's hard enough to implement a decent non-`constexpr` trig function, let alone `constexpr` one.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for pointing that out. I had never tried that myself. I, however, made my own library for doing some compile-time stuff https://github.com/lakshayg/compile_time/  and I am quite sure that it can handle this case well. Do give it a try and let me know (or open an issue) if you have suggestions (This is still a work in progress).

Comment: Didn't look at the code, but your version 1) fails to include `<stdexcept>`, thus not compiling without tweaks; 2) seems to do only trivial range reduction, so that e.g. `compile_time::cos(200.)` differs considerably from `std::cos(200.)` on x86_64 gcc, while for argument of `2.` the results are more or less the same. Even worse for `long double`. But yes, it does appear to at least attempt to do range reduction, unlike `static_math`.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the feedback, could you please provide me some details about your platform. On my machine (linux, x86_64, g++5.4) the code compiles without any warnings/errors and the error is less than 0.00001%. Also, we should probably continue this discussion on github.

Comment: Yeah, made an issue report. Anyway, the problem with precision isn't what fraction of percent it is — it's how many ULPs it is. In my test I got the error of `2**17` ULP, which is no good for IEEE754 64-bit `double`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and fix this.