# using constexpr double in namespaces

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm currently getting into more C++11 stuff and jumped about `constexpr`. In one of my books it's said that you should use it for constants like π for example in this way:

```
#include <cmath>

// (...)

constexpr double PI = atan(1) * 4;
```

Now I wanted to put that in an own namespace, eg. `MathC`:

```
// config.h

#include <cmath>

namespace MathC {
    constexpr double PI = atan(1) * 4;
    // further declarations here
}
```

...but here IntelliSense says `function call must have a constant value in a constant expression`.

When I declare `PI` the following way, it works:

```
static const double PI = atan(1) * 4;
```

What is the actual reason the compiler doesn't seem to like `constexpr` but `static const` here? Shouldn't `constexpr` be eligible here, too, or is it all about the context here and `constexpr`shouldn't be declared outside of functions?

Thank you.

Comment: [`atan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan) is not `constexpr`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347935/constexpr-math-functions).

Comment: What book are you using and what page/section is this code in.

Comment: So it seems like this is a mistake by the book author then. It's a german book called "C++ - Das umfassende Handbuch" by Jürgen Wolf, published in Rheinwerk Computing, 2nd edition in 2014, page 250. It clearly says `constexpr double PI_V3 = atan(1)*4;`.

Comment: can you please share which book is that?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ sure, here's the German Amazon link: https://www.amazon.de/umfassende-Handbuch-aktuell-Standard-Computing/dp/3836220210

Answer (score 5):

> What is the actual reason the compiler doesn't seem to like `constexpr` but `static const` here?

A `constexpr` must be evaluatable at compile time while `static const` does not need to be.

```
static const double PI = atan(1) * 4;
```

simply tells the compiler that `PI` may not be modified once it is initialized but it may be initialized at run time.