# How to calculate Euler constant or Euler powered in C++?

Tags: c++, eulers-number

I am trying to find the more 'natural' way to use the number *e* in C/C++. I am focused on calculating the function *e*^n.

I think that 'cmath', by default, does not provide support for both (function and constant). However, it can be enabled to include constants defined by the compiler, in this case, `M_E`. This can be done by including the statement `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`.

On the other hand, *e* can be defined as a constant:

```
#define E 2.71828182845904523536;
```

or

```
const double EULER = 2.71828182845904523536;
```

Said this. Which one is the most 'standard' way to approach to this mathematical constant? Is it any other library?

Comment: in calculcating *e^n*, is `n` an integer, real, or complex? Only if it's an integer, will `std::pow(Euler,n)` possibly be more efficient than simply `std::exp(n)`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you can avoid using a preprocessor symbol you should. It will cause you trouble when you least expect it. `E` is likely going to be a variable.

Proposed solution:

```
#include <cmath>
const double EulerConstant = std::exp(1.0);
```

The advantage of calculating the constant instead of assigning a floating point literal is that it will produce a result with precision that matches the precision of the `double` data type for your particular C++ implementation. And it removes the possibility of introducing an error by accidentally skipping a digit.

As illustrated above, `<cmath>` does declare [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp), so there is no need for you to roll your own.

Comment: Agree! And const double is better than #define. See Scott Meyers' "Effective C++" Idiom 1

Comment: It should also be noted that `std::exp` takes a power argument, so if you are looking to calculate `e^n`, storing the constant is superfluous since you can just write it as `std::exp(n)`.

Answer (score 7):

**C++20 `std::numbers::e`**

C++20 has also added an `e` constant to the standard library: http://eel.is/c++draft/numbers

I expect the usage to be like:

```
#include <math>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numbers::e << std::endl;
}
```

I'll give it a try when support arrives to GCC, GCC 9.1.0 with `g++-9 -std=c++2a` still doesn't support it.

The accepted proposal describes:

> 5.0. “Headers” [headers]
>   In the table [tab:cpp.library.headers], a new  header needs to be added.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> namespace std {
> namespace math { 
> template<typename T > inline constexpr T e_v = unspecified;
> inline constexpr double e = e_v<double>;
> ```

There is also a `std::numbers::pi` of course :-) [How to use the PI constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c/57285400#57285400)

These constants use the C++14 variable template feature: [C++14 Variable Templates: what is their purpose? Any usage example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051141/c14-variable-templates-what-is-their-purpose-any-usage-example)

In earlier versions of the draft, the constant was under `std::math::e`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0631r7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am just facing this school problem as well, and figured out I'd have Euler's number calculated without cmath.  So we need to calculate 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + ... + 1/n!.

I use recursive functions to achieve so like this (the main is only for testing my solution about e) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double Factorial(int n){    // Max n = 170
    if(n==1) return 1;
    else return n * Factorial(n-1);
}

double GetEuler(int n){
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    else return (1/Factorial(n) + GetEuler(n-1));
}

int main(){
    int n;
    double e;

    e = GetEuler(170);
    cout << setprecision(15) << e << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output : 2.71828182845905