# C++14 Variable Templates: what is their purpose? Any usage example?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

C++14 will allow the creation of variables that are templated. The usual example is a variable 'pi' that can be read to get the value of the mathematical constant π for various types (3 for `int`; the closest value possible with `float`, etc.)

Besides that we can have this feature just by wrapping a variable within a templated struct or class, how does this mix with type conversions? I see some overlapping.

And other than the `pi` example, how would it work with non-`const` variables? Are there any usage examples to understand how to make the most of such a feature and what its purpose is?

Comment: The proposal [N3651](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf) seems to cover a lot of this information.

Comment: See [What is the purpose of _t aliases and _v variable templates for type traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77083721/5740428)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> And other than the pi example, how would it work with non-const
>   variables?

Currently, it seems to instantiate the variables separately for the type. i.e., you could assign 10 to `n<int>` and it would be different from the template definition.

```
template<typename T>
T n = T(5);

int main()
{
    n<int> = 10;
    std::cout << n<int> << " ";    // 10
    std::cout << n<double> << " "; // 5
}
```

If the declaration is `const`, it is readonly. If it's a `constexpr`, like all `constexpr` declarations, it has not much use outside `constexpr`(ressions).

> Besides that we can have this feature just by wrapping a variable
>   within a templated struct or class, how does this mix with type
>   conversions?

It's meant to be a simple proposal. I am unable to see how it affects type conversions in a significant way. As I already stated, the type of the variable is the type you instantiated the template with. i.e., `decltype(n<int>)` is int. `decltype((double)n<int>)` is double and so on.

> Any usage example to understand how to make the most of such a feature
>   and what its purpose is?

[N3651](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf) provides a succinct rationale.

> Alas, existing C++ rules do not allow a template declaration to
>   declare a variable. There are well known workarounds for this
>   problem:
>
> > • use constexpr static data members of class templates
> >
> > • use constexpr function templates returning the desired values
>
> These workarounds have been known for decades and well documented.
>   Standard classes such as std::numeric_limits are archetypical
>   examples. Although these workarounds aren’t perfect, their drawbacks
>   were tolerable to some degree because in the C++03 era only simple,
>   builtin types constants enjoyed unfettered direct and efficient
>   compile time support. All of that changed with the adoption of
>   constexpr variables in C++11, which extended the direct and efficient
>   support to constants of user-defined types. Now, programmers are
>   making constants (of class types) more and more apparent in programs.
>   So grow the confusion and frustrations associated with the
>   workarounds.

...

> The main problems with "static data member" are:
>
> > • they require "duplicate" declarations: once inside the class
> >     template, once outside the class template to provide the "real"
> >     definition in case the con- stants is odr-used.
> >
> > • programmers are both miffed and confused by the necessity of providing twice the same
> >     declaration. By contrast, "ordinary" constant declarations do not need
> >     duplicate declarations.

...

> Well known examples in this category are probably static member
>   functions of numeric_limits, or functions such as
>   `boost::constants::pi<T>()`, etc. Constexpr functions templates do not
>   suffer the "duplicate declarations" issue that static data members
>   have; furthermore, they provide functional abstraction. However, they
>   force the programmer to chose in advance, at the definition site, how
>   the constants are to be delivered: either by a const reference, or by
>   plain non- reference type. If delivered by const reference then the
>   constants must be systematically be allocated in static storage; if
>   by non-reference type, then the constants need copying. Copying isn’t
>   an issue for builtin types, but it is a showstopper for user-defined
>   types with value semantics that aren’t just wrappers around tiny
>   builtin types (e.g. matrix, or integer, or bigfloat, etc.) By
>   contrast, "ordinary" const(expr) variables do not suffer from this
>   problem. A simple definition is provided, and the decision of
>   whether the constants actually needs to be layout out in storage only
>   depends on the usage, not the definition.

Answer (score 34):

> we can have this feature just by wrapping a variable within a templated struct or class

Yes, but that would be gratuitous syntactic salt. Not healthy for the blood pressure.

`pi<double>` conveys the intent better than `pi<double>::value`. Short and to the point. That's enough of a reason in my book to allow and encourage this syntax.

Answer (score 15):

Another practical example for C++14's variable templates is when you need a function for passing something into `std::accumulate`:

```
template<typename T>
T const & (*maxer) (T const &, T const &) = std::max<T>;

std::accumulate(some.begin(), some.end(), initial, maxer<float>);
```

Note that using `std::max<T>` is insufficient because it can't deduce the exact signature. In this particular example you can use `max_element` instead, but the point is that there is a whole class of functions that share this behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I wonder whether something along these lines would be possible: (assuming availability of template lambdas)

```
void some_func() {
    template<typename T>
    std::map<int, T> storage;

    auto store = []<typename T>(int key, const T& value) { storage<T>[key] = value; };

    store(0, 2);
    store(1, "Hello"s);
    store(2, 0.7);

    // All three values are stored in a different map, according to their type. 
}
```

Now, is this useful?

As a simpler use, notice that the initialization of `pi<T>` uses explicit conversion (explicit call of a unary constructor) and not uniform initialization. Which means that, given a type `radians` with a constructor `radians(double)`, you can write `pi<radians>`.

Comment: Unfortunately your code isn't valid. The proposal doesn't make that any syntax changes. `The reason is that the
current grammar allows any declaration to be parameterized`. Try it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) using `clang++ --std=c++1y`.

Comment: @remyabel: I don't get it. I used two features: template variables and template lambdas. Template lambdas are not accepted yet.

Comment: Oh, generic lambdas. It still won't compile, but I've tried to get close to it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54ab174f073762c2

Comment: I corrected the lambda code in my post. I used `[key] = value` instead of `insert`.

Comment: Crud! It does not work. I can't capture `storage` in the lambda because it's not a variable. It's a variable template...

Comment: I have a compiling example at [the question I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188052/variable-templates-generic-lambdas-for-stdmap) (scroll to the bottom for the live example link), however it requires explicit instantiations for every pair you will use, and each map is a different variable.

Comment: Indeed. It kinda defeats the purpose. The only remaining solution for my idea to work is a global variable template with a free function template.

Comment: The prohibition against so-called ‘local templates’ in C++ is a longstanding one — even in the face of upcoming polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: You can already do something similar to this using the `using` keyword: `template<typename T> using store = map<std::string, T>;`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: That only creates a new templated type name, it does not declare one variable per type argument.

Comment: There are means to get it to compile, but there are link errors (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5db647f2bf85420f).  The `storage` cannot be local, and generic lambdas now exist.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use this to write compile time code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N> const int ctSquare = N*N;

int main() {
    std::cout << ctSquare<7> << std::endl;
}
```

This is a significant improvement over the equivalent

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N> struct ctSquare {
    static const int value = N*N;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << ctSquare<7>::value << std::endl;
}
```

that people used to write to perform template metaprogramming before variable templates were introduced. For non-type values, we were able to do this since C++11 with `constexpr`, so template variables have only the advantage of allowing computations based on types to the variable templates.

TL;DR: They don't allow us to do anything we couldn't do before, but they make template metaprogramming less of a PITA.

Comment: Between this feature and the shorthands/helpers like `std::conditional_t`, etc. I often wonder why they came so late. The "[rules of thumb](https://accu.org/content/conf2013/Bjarnes_Talk.pdf)" make sense in principal, but items like "Don’t add features just to follow fashion" and “being able to do something is not sufficient reason for doing it” sure sound like explanations for the flak C++ TMP syntax takes. Maybe if I knew more about the TR/TS process I'd understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have a use case here.

```
template<typename CT> constexpr CT MARK = '%';
template<> constexpr wchar_t MARK<wchar_t> = L'%';
```

which are used in a string processing template.`

```
template <typename CT> 
void ProcessString(const std::basic_string<CT>& str)
{
    auto&& markpos = str.find(MARK<CT>);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: `CT` is apparently short for character type but it's just ambiguous. You could use `charT` or `char_type` instead.