# Variable templates + generic lambdas for std::map

Tags: c++, c++14

An [answer to C++14 Variable Templates: what is the purpose? Any usage example?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21162680/1508519) proposes a usage example of variable templates + generic lambdas that would look something like this:

```
void some_func() {
    template<typename T>
    std::map<int, T> storage;

    auto store = []<typename T>(int key, const T& value) { storage<T>.insert(key, value) };

    store(0, 2);
    store(1, "Hello"s);
    store(2, 0.7);

    // All three values are stored in a different map, according to their type. 
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile so I've tried to "fix" it and this is my attempt so far.

```
#include <map>

template<typename T>
std::map<int, T> storage;

void some_func() {

    auto store = [](int key, const auto& value) { storage<decltype(value)>.insert(key, value); };

    store(0, 2);
    store(1, std::string("Hello"));
    store(2, 0.7);
}
```

The error message are:

```
main.cpp:7:76: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'

    auto store = [](int key, const auto& value) { storage<decltype(value)>.insert(key, value); };
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
main.cpp:10:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'some_func()::<anonymous class>::operator()<std::basic_string<char> >' requested here

    store(1, std::string("Hello"));
```

When you instantiate a variable template, like all templates, each variable will be a different type. The theory is `auto` doesn't get deduced for each type, but only one type initially (double). Therefore the code is invalid. Even if this *could* work, each instantiation of storage would refer to a different variable.

How can this code be rewritten to achieve the original intent?

---

**Edit** I made a small mistake in my edit (see revision history to avoid wall of text.) `decltype(pair)` should be `decltype(pair.second)` since there is only one template argument for `storage`.

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
std::map<int, T> storage;

void some_func() {
    auto store = [&](auto pair) { storage<decltype(pair.second)>.insert(pair); };

    store(std::pair<int, int>(0, 1));
    store(std::pair<int, std::string>(1, "Hello!"));
    store(std::pair<int, int>(2, 3));
}

int main()
{
}
```

There are now linker errors.

```
/tmp/main-5f1f7c.o: In function `some_func()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `storage<int>'
main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `storage<std::string>'
main.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `storage<int>'
```

In order to fix the linker errors, I think you need to explicitly instantiate the arguments? (I'm not even sure if that's the correct term here.)

```
template <typename T>
std::map<int, T> storage;

template <>
std::map<int, int> storage<int>;

template <>
std::map<int, std::string> storage<std::string>;
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d181048cb2999d6a)

Comment: Can you describe at a high level what the original intent actually is?  That is, what is the idea we are trying to implement using code like this?

Comment: Also have you made sure that your compiler supports variable templates?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) which has clang 3.5.

Comment: I think the problem is: That is not a capturing lambda, so the map (Even if its a global variable) is not being captured by the lambda.

Comment: Lambda signature is right??? Shouldn't the lambda be: `auto store = [&] (decltype(storage)::value_type val) { storage.insert(val); };`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I think you could do `[&]<class T>(decltype(storage<T>)::value_type val)`, but for some reason, that syntax won't compile.

Comment: That would be the incorrect signature though. See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01d73c0fdaf0ead1

The radius example is taken from open-std.. It does not compile so I'd assume that clang++ does NOT support template variables yet. However, take a look at the function signature I commented out. That would work if clang++ supports template variables. Not sure that it does atm.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I see a linker error, not a compiler error. You need to do the `template <>
constexpr int pi<int> = int(3.1415926535897932385);
` like I posted in my edit, but I'm not sure if that's even the correct syntax.

Comment: You're right but then that just gets rid of the point of the template variable imo.. To get rid of the template parameter by explicitly specifying a type.. might as well get rid of the template. It's useful though because then you have one variable name representing many different types I guess. Btw, I got the example I had from: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf

Comment: @Manu343726 Beginning with the second example, the `map` is a global. Globals don't have to be captured; only automatic variables and `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
std::map<int, T> storage;
```

This is a declaration, much like e.g. `template<typename T> class foo;`. As we need one anyway, we would benefit from making it a definition as well:

```
template<typename T>
std::map<int, T> storage {};
```

This doesn’t get rid of the linker errors however, suggesting there’s an outstanding bug with implicit instantiation. To convince ourselves, we can trigger instantiation in various ways:

- explicitly, which would look like

  ```
  // namespace scope, same as storage
  template /* sic */ std::map<int, int>         storage<int>;
  template           std::map<int, std::string> storage<std::string>;
  ```
- implicitly, by adding the following inside `main`

  ```
  storage<int>.size();
  storage<std::string>.size();
  ```

in either case taming the linker.

What you attempted is explicit *specialization*, which does indeed get around the issue although using a different mechanism.

Comment: Yes, works/fails as described :) with clang++3.5 trunk 199418