# Can I use a variable template to declare another variable template?

Tags: c++, c++14, variable-templates

With variable templates coming in C++14 (and Clang already supporting them) and a proposal for standard `is_same_v` and likewise type traits, I figured being able to make new type traits as follows would be neat:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_const_and_volatile{std::is_const_v<T> && std::is_volatile_v<T>};
```

Alas, this results in errors equivalent to the following SSCCE ([this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af5af0b38e106fff) contains everything mentioned below):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_pointer{std::is_pointer<T>::value};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool foo{is_pointer<T>};

int main() {
    //foo<int *>;
}
```

With the line in `main` commented, Clang spits out the following:

> warning: variable `is_pointer<type-parameter-0-0>` has internal linkage but is not defined

It looks defined to me (note that changing `T` to `int *` in `foo` works fine). Uncommenting the line in `main` to instantiate `foo` gives this (again, `T` to `int *` works fine):

> error: constexpr variable `foo<int *>` must be initialized by a constant expression

However, replacing `foo` with the following old syntax causes both instances to work fine:

```
constexpr bool foo{std::is_pointer<T>::value};
```

Is there something I'm missing about variable templates? Is there a way to build new variable templates *with* them, or am I forced to use the older syntax to build new ones and only enjoy the syntactic sugar when using them for other code?

Comment: Have you tried explicit instantiation? Luc Danton spotted [a bug related to implicit instantiation recently..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21234048/420683)

Comment: (Seems to "work" with explicit instantiation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e16d249679a71d0c)

Comment: @dyp, Ok, but adding one for `bool *` in your example [still gives the linker error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/990bc676207518a2), unfortunately, not to mention the fact that I can't possibly explicitly instantiate it for every type.

Comment: I read through http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf. And I think it should work. It looks to me like a clang bug.

Comment: @chris I only see warnings in your example. It's also clear that adding explicit instantiations doesn't help suppress the general warning that the primary template `is_pointer` is "not defined". And of course that's only meant to show that there's a relation to implicit instantiation, it's not meant as a solution.

Comment: @dyp, Sorry, I meant warning. I think it's the wording of the warning making me repeatedly think it's a linker error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is valid, and is accepted by clang SVN. The link error was caused by [clang bug 17846](http://llvm.org/PR17846), which I [fixed a couple of days ago](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140203/098398.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct test {
    static constexpr bool is_pointer{std::is_pointer<T>::value};
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool test<T>::is_pointer;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool foo{test<T>::is_pointer};

int main() {
    std::cout << foo<bool>;
    std::cout << foo<bool*>;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6957667f34501a8b)

Although it procs the same warning if used in a `constexpr` context so I suppose it doesn't really work after all.

```
// Fail
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<foo<T>, void>::type bar()
{
}

int main() {
    bar<bool*>();
}

main.cpp:21:5: error: no matching function for call to 'bar'

    bar<bool*>();

    ^~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:16:45: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = bool *]: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

typename std::enable_if<foo<T>, void>::type bar()
```

It does stop complaining if you give `foo` an explicit type:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<foo<bool*>, void>::type bar()
{
}
```

Or just use `test<T>::is_pointer` directly:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<test<T>::is_pointer, void>::type bar()
{
}
```