# Conditional template variable

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T >
using cond =
    std::conditional_t<
        std::is_void< T >::value ,
        std::true_type ,
        std::false_type
    >::value;

static_assert( cond< void > , "" );

int main() {}
```

[Example clang 3.6](http://goo.gl/TvyAVq)

```
missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::conditional_t::value, std::true_type, std::false_type>::value'
```

Why is it missing a `typename` as it isn't a type at all?
If I add the `typename` it throws this at me:

```
error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'value' in 'std::integral_constant<bool, true>'
```

Isn't it the same thing as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051141/c14-variable-templates-what-is-the-purpose-any-usage-example)?
How do I resolve this?

Comment: `using`, [in that form](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), expects a typename.  Not a value.

Comment: what's the point in using `conditional_t` with `true_type` and `false_type`, if you can use `std::is_void< T >::value` directly ?

Comment: Ahhh.. i was struggling for over an hour and then i realised that most online compilers use g++ < 5.0 and only since 5.0 template variables were supported (and th error messages didnt helped either). After that I forgot to use the right syntax... its so obvious, I even linked to the other question..

Comment: @PiotrS. this was just an example, the condition could be anything (had template templates in my mind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use [template aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to alias types. The right syntax for your variable template is

```
template< typename T >
constexpr bool cond = std::conditional_t< std::is_void< T >::value,
                      std::true_type,
                      std::false_type >::value;
```

While the error message your code gets is a bit confusing, adding the suggested `typename` results in this more helpful message with clang 3.6

```
error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'value' in
       'std::integral_constant'

using cond = typename std::conditional_t< std::is_void< T >::value,
^~~~~                 std::true_type,
                      std::false_type >::value;
```

which explains the real problem.

Comment: Thanks, I immediately realized at the second I saw your and the other (deleted) anwer

Comment: Why not `template< typename T > constexpr bool cond = std::is_void< T >::value`???

Comment: @Orient Because I was staying faithful to the rest of the code in the question :)