# Should I use unnamed temporary tag or named tag instance in tag dispatch?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

When implementing tag extraction for tag dispatch (in C++11), should I prefer to use an unnamed temporary tag instance, or a named tag instance?

I am asking for a "best practice," although pros/cons would also be useful. I'd like to maximize the chances that the empty temporary tag instances are eliminated. I have read somewhere that using an unnamed temporary might help with optimization, but I don't know whether it matters in practice.

Here's an example of both forms:

```
struct apple_fruit_tag {};
struct orange_fruit_tag {};

class SomeType {
 public:
    using fruit_category = apple_fruit_tag; 
};

namespace detail {
  template<typename T>
  void doSomething_(T x, apple_tag) { /* ... */ }
  template<typename T>
  void doSomething_(T x, orange_tag) { /* ... */ }
}
```

**Option #1: type alias, unnamed temporary tag instance**

This is the form used [here](https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/tutorial-on-tag-dispatching/) (crazycpp.wordpress.com).

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T x)
{
  using f_t = typename T::fruit_category;
  detail::doSomething_(x, f_t{});
}
```

**Option #2: named tag instance**

This is the form used [here](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html) (boost.org).

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T x)
{
  typename T::fruit_category f;
  detail::doSomething_(x, f);
}
```

For completeness, here's an example `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    SomeType x;
    doSomething(x);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any worthwhile difference between the two.

Comment: What is wrong with `detail::doSomething_(x, typename T::fruit_category{});` ? .

Comment: ... or `detail::doSomething_(x, tag<T>());` where `tag` is a function template which returns an object of type `T::fruit_category`. In C++14, [variable template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051141/c14-variable-templates-what-is-their-purpose-any-usage-example) would make it look like : `detail::doSomething_(x, tag<T>);` where `tag` is a variable-template defined as `template<typename T> typename T::fruit_category tag{};`

Comment: @Nawaz: this question is about C++11 not C++14. Your options are valid, in practice I do have a `tag<T>` template. But my `tag<T>` has multiple parameters, so it's a bit long to fit in a function call; and I sometimes need to use its result in multiple `detail::foo` sub-dispatches, so i think it makes sense to only instantiate it once.

Comment: @RossBencina: I don't see any problem in any of the approaches here. I don't know what *specific problem* you're facing.

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks. the *specific problem* is my uncertainty about which of the options in the question is *best practice* (assuming that I want to store some representation of the tag or its type prior to using it). I'm preparing library documentation, and I don't want to mislead clients by telling them to write sub-optimal code.

Comment: @RossBencina: I prefer *pointer* to tag (like `f(static_cast<SomeTag const*>(0)`)) so that it is inexpensive to create. This along with `tag` function template simplifies the code: `f(tag<Some>());`; now `tag` returns a *null* pointer to the tag corresponding to the type `Some`.