# What is the purpose of _t aliases and _v variable templates for type traits?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, language-design, type-traits

There are *a lot* of `*_v` and `*_t` suffixes, like `std::is_same_v`, `std::invoke_result_t`, `result_of_t` and milions of other such functions.

*Why* do they exist at all? Is it beneficial in any context to expose implementation details like `std::result_of::type` or `std::is_same::value`? Ignoring standard compliance, should the `_v` `_t` versions *always* be preferred? Could the `::type` `::value` versions  have never existed at all?

Comment: They were added as more-readable aliases to the nested types. I personally don't find the nested types particularly hard to read in the first place. Though there are [particular linters that will enforce this](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-6020/). As far as your last question, no I don't think that's quite true as at the end of the day both `::type` and `::value` are dependent types on `T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_t` alias templates were introduced in C++14 and the `_v` variable templates in C++17. There are many good reasons for why these exist.

#### The `_t` and `_v` templates are more convenient.

Firstly, `trait_t<T>` is five characters shorter than `trait<T>::type`. Furthermore, you would need to prefix the latter with `typename` because the compiler cannot infer whether `::type` is a a type or a static member. See also [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/5740428).

This can make a big difference, comparing C++11/C++17 code:

```cpp
// C++17
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>> foo();
// C++11
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<T>::value>::type foo();
```

#### The `_t` and `_v` templates offer more implementation freedom.

The fact that the traits are all classes is a significant limitation. It means that each use of e.g. `std::is_same` will have to instantiate a new class template, and this is relatively costly. Modern compilers implement all type traits as intrinsics, similar to:

```cpp
template <typename _A, typename _B>
struct is_same {
    static constexpr bool value = __is_same(_A, _B);
};

template <typename _A, typename _B>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = __is_same(_A, _B);
```

*See [`__type_traits/is_same.h` in libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6d2aaa5fdb828614b20f79ebf6089c5a1babf5b5/libcxx/include/__type_traits/is_same.h#L21-L27).*

The class is obviously redundant and it would be much more efficient to use the built-in function directly through a variable template.

#### Are trait classes pointless now that `_t` and `_v` exist?

The answer depends on the compiler.
A common argument in favor of the classes is that they allow short-circuiting.
For example, you can replace

```cpp
(std::is_same_v<Ts, int> && ...)
// with
std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Ts, int>...>
```

... and unlike the fold expression, not all `std::is_same` will be instantiated.
However, at least for clang and GCC, the cost of instantiating `std::is_same_v` is so trivially cheap (thanks to it being a built-in) that even though fold expressions don't short-circuit, it's still better for compilation speed to use them.

[image: benchmark results showing that the use of fold expressions is 1.2 times faster than std::conjunction/std::disjunction]
*Click on image to go to benchmark results*

However, older compilers might implement some traits using actual classes instead of built-ins, so it's theoretically possible that short-circuiting would be better.

#### Trait classes are sometimes more convenient for TMP.

Regardless of performance, the traits are sometimes useful for metaprogramming, such as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Select;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Select<Pair<A, B>> : std::conditional<LeftIsBetter<A, B>, A, B> {};
// is more concise than
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Select<Pair<A, B>> {
    using type = std::conditional_t<LeftIsBetter<A, B>, A, B>;
};
```

Inheriting from trait classes is convenient in some cases, although not strictly necessary.

#### See Also

You can find rationale and further explanation of `_t` and `_v` alias/variable templates in the following papers:

- [N3655 - TransformationTraits Redux, v2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf)
- [N3854 - Variable Templates For Type Traits](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm)
- [P0006 - Adopt Type Traits Variable Templates from Library Fundamentals TS for C++17](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html)

Comment: note that the `_t` naming convention is actually encoded by POSIX which reserves all names ending in `_t` for typenames (which in C++ and with namespaces shouldn't interfere of course).

Comment: `are sometimes useful for metaprogramming, such as:` To clarify, it is not possible to write the `Select<Pair<A, B>` using `template<...> using Select_t = ...`? Or the resulting code is then not readable? I was able to write this https://godbolt.org/z/oMn5EsMbY , and it looks quite nice, but I do not know how to match `template<std::pair T>` properly. My point is, if you can express everything with `_t` form as with `::type`, or the other way round, why have both interfaces? Concise is an argument.

Comment: @KamilCuk this only works because you're relying on the type having a `::first_type` and `::second_type` alias. The properties you obtain about a type are often not conveniently obtained through aliases. For example, if you're deducing properties such as the size or type of an array, then there are no aliases available, and you must use a class. In the specific case of `std::pair`, there is `::first_type` and `::second_type`, but that's not always the case. The example is just meant to demonstrate what to do in such an event.

Answer (score 21):

TL;DR - `_t` aliases can shorten metaprogramming code significantly due to omitting `::type` and `typename`. `_v` variable templates were added later for symmetry with `_t` aliases and because they're just better in every way.

#### C++17 - `_v` variable templates

Here's a quote from [proposal paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm) that introduced `_v` variable templates into C++17:

> Variable templates like is_same_v<T, U> are superior to nested
> constants like is_same<T, U>::value for several reasons:
>
> 1. Obviously, the former is 5 characters shorter.
> 2. Less obviously, the former eliminates "disconnected verbosity". When working with type traits, it's common to have to say things like
>    enable_if_t<!is_same<X, decay_t>::value, Z>, where "is_same" and
>    "::value" are separated by a potentially substantial amount of
>    machinery.
> 3. Having to say "::value" isn't a feature, it's a workaround for a language limitation that has been solved. (Note that this proposal
>    doesn't touch the struct templates, so metaprogrammers who want the
>    is_same type instead of its nested constant are unaffected.)

Also, important points from the [adoption paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html):

> Following the success of the `_t` alias templates for type traits, a matching set of `_v` variable templates have been proposed. The language support for variable templates arrived too late to confidently make this change for C++14, but experience since has shown that such variable templates are more succinct, can clean up the text in a similar way that the `_t` aliases have been widely adopted through the standard, and the author's experience using them in his own implementation of the standard type traits library is that code is much simpler when written using such variable templates directly, rather than turning a value into a type, then performing template manipulations on the type, before turning the type back into a value.
> The impact on the standard is that many places that reference `some_trait<T>::value` would instead use `some_trait_v<T>`. The saving is not quite as great as in the case of alias templates, as there is no irksome `typename` to remove. However, the consistecy of using `_t` and `_v` to refer to traits, and not using `::something` to extract meaning is compelling.

#### C++14 - `_t` aliases

Similar reasoning was provided in [paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf) that introduced `_t` aliases in C++14, with the extra benefit of adding `typename`, which NathanOliver remarked in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77083773/7976805). Quote from the paper:

> Unfortunately, the above-described flexibility comes with a cost for the most common use cases.
> In a template context, C++ requires that each “metacall” to a metafunction bear syntactic overhead
> in the form of an introductory `typename` keyword, as well as the suffixed `::type`:
>
> ```
> typename metafunction-name<metafunction-argument(s)>::type
> ```
>
> Even relatively straightforward compositions can rather quickly become somewhat messy; deeper
> nesting is downright unwieldy:
>
> ```
> template< class T > using reference_t
>    = typename conditional<is_reference<T>::value, T,
>                           typename add_lvalue_reference<T>::type>::type;
> ```
>
> Worse, accidentally omitting the keyword can lead to diagnostics that are arcane to programmers
> who are inexpert in metaprogramming details.
>
> In our experience, passing metafunctions (rather than metadata) constitutes a relatively
> small fraction of metafunction compositions. We find ourselves passing metafunction results
> far more frequently. We therefore propose to add a set of template aliases for the library’s
> `TransformationTraits` in order to reduce the programmer burden of expressing this far more
> common case. Note, in the following rewrite of the above example, the absence of any `typename`
> keyword, as well as the absence of any `::type` suffix, thus condensing the statement from 3 to 2
> lines of code:
>
> ```
> template< class T > using reference_t
>     = conditional_t< is_reference<T>::value, T, add_lvalue_reference_t<T> >;
> ```

Answer (score 17):

The issue is that when you have `std::result_of<TEMPLATE_STUFF>::type`, `type` is a dependent name and as such needs to be qualifed with `typename` in order to inform the compiler that `type` is the name of a type and not a object.  The `*_t` names are aliases to `typename trait_name::type` so you don't have to type `typename` yourself.

The `typename` is not needed for the `*_v`s since those are values, but it keeps a consistent syntax and is still less typing.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it beneficial in any context to expose implementation details like std::result_of::type or std::is_same::value?

They are not implementation details. These are the original interfaces that are intended to be used.

The `_t` variants have to be implemented as *alias templates* which only exist since C++11 and the `_v` variants have to be implemented as *variable templates* which only exist since C++14.

So originally it simply wasn't possible to define the interface without the indirection through `::type` or `::value` members. The short-hand versions have been added later and don't do anything but safe some typing and making code easier to read.

The `_t` variants could have been added directly with C++11, but the type traits had already been considered for inclusion into C++11 very early on. Presumably alias templates were added to the draft later or the `::type` interface was already familiar because type trait implementations have existed before C++11 as well.

If you are writing C++17 or later code that doesn't need to be compatible with earlier C++ versions, there is (almost) no reason to not use the `_t` and `_v` variants instead of the old `::type`/`::value` interfaces. If you need to support older C++ versions, then you should use `::type`/`::value` accordingly, until up to C++11 and C++14 respectively.

In case of `::value` it is occasionally useful to use the type trait itself rather than the `::value` member. Because the type trait is defined to be derived from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` according to how it evaluates, this allows one to keep the logic at the type level without any detours.

Sometimes it is also useful to use the `::value`/`::type` members only conditionally in templates. In that case they have the advantage that the type trait needs to be instantiated only when `::value`/`::type` appears in an instantiated context. Because the instantiation can, depending on the type trait, cause many other instantiations and might have UB if the type is not yet complete.

Newly-added type traits still follow the same scheme for consistency.

Comment: Re: _"Newly-added type traits still follow the same scheme for consistency"_ - it may be good to mention that some type traits depend on the base (non-`_v`)  trait to exist, like `std::conjunction`/`std::disjunction`

Comment: `there is no reason to not use the _t and _v variants instead of the old ::type/::value interface` Overall, this is the answer I am looking for. But then,, I wonder, _what is the point_ of `std::invoke_result` available from C++17 if `std::invoke_result_t` should always be preferred? Could `std::invoke_result` be removed?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I guess you got the answer to the follow up question towards the bottom of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77088083/5825294).