# Numeric constants in C++

Tags: c++

1. Are numeric constant makros like `M_PI` known from the C-library `math.h` part of the C++ standard?
   I cannot find them in my [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath).
2. What is the best way to define custom constants?
   Is a `constants.hpp` with `static constexpr int foo = 7;` with a special namespace a good solution?
3. If the makros from question 1 do exist, should I prefer them for readability or define my own constants (like in 2 or in a better way) for type safety?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1727881/1147772 Might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the C Standard nor the C++ Standard defines constant `M_PI`.

There is no sense to use keyword static in a constant definition because by default constants have internal linkage.

Before defining a constant you should look through the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 3):

You could use boost -

```
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>

using namespace  boost::math::constants;

double circumference(double radius)
{
    return radius * 2 * pi<double>();
}
```

see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/constants.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. `M_PI` is not standard.
2. I think this is more of a preference.  I've seen the following methods:

   ```
   #define PI 3.1415
   const double PI = 3.1415;
   const double kPi = 3.1415;
   ```
3. Again, I think its a preference or it could depend on what you are actually doing.  Also try this:

   ```
   #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
   #include <math.h>
   ```