# How can I calculate pi using Bash command

Tags: bash, shell, seq, bc

I am learning bash scripting. While exploring the math functions i am came across a command which calculated the value of pi.

```
seq -f '4/%g' 1 2 99999 | paste -sd-+ | bc -l
```

Although i understand how the basic seq command works, I am unable to understand how does the above command works. Can anybody please clarify how does it work.?

Comment: Why can it not be as simple as this: `bc -l <<< 'scale=5; 22/7'`

Comment: Check on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) section named **Continued fractions**.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, but `π` is not `22/7`.

Comment: Sure I know that but even this `seq` is also approximation albeit a better one no doubt.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/275516/how-can-i-generate-pi-to-a-given-number-of-decimal-places-from-a-script

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This calculates the value of π using Gregory–Leibniz series:

[image]

`seq -f '4/%g' 1 2 99999` generates the fractions:

```
4/1
4/3
4/5
4/7
4/9
4/11
4/13
4/15
4/17
4/19
```

The paste pipeline `paste -sd-+` combines those with alternate delimiters `-` and `+`.

Finally, `bc -l` performs the arithmetic to give the result.

---

EDIT:  As noted in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524661/how-can-i-calculate-pi-using-bash-command/23524782#comment36087051_23524782), this sequence converges very slowly.  [Machin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Machin) has a significantly higher rate of convergence:

[image]

Using the same expansion for tan<sup>-1</sup>(x):

[image]

to compute π, we can see that it produces the correct value to 50 digits<sup>1</sup> using just the first 50 terms of the series:

```
$ { echo -n "scale=50;"; seq 1 2 100 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo '(16*(1/5)^{}/{}-4*(1/239)^{}/{})';} | paste -sd-+ | bc -l
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
```

With just 100 terms, the value of π is computed accurately to more than 100 digits:

```
$ { echo -n "scale=100;"; seq 1 2 200 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo '(16*(1/5)^{}/{}-4*(1/239)^{}/{})';} | paste -sd-+ | bc -l
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

<sup>1</sup> [Pi](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Pi/)

Comment: And that sequence converges *very* slowly. You need over 1500 iterations to get an approximation better than 22/7.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're correct.  The edit computes π using Machin's formula which converges _much_ faster.

Answer (score 20):

Not a direct answer to your question about using `seq`, but pi can be easily computed using `bc`:

```
 echo "scale=1000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

`a` is arctan, and this give pi to 1000 digits.

Comment: You could pipe `sed 's/.$//'` at the end and change it to `scale=1001` because the last digit gets fudged but I still like this answer.

Comment: @mchid or also you can pipe `xargs` for the same reason of getting rid of `\`'s at the EOL

Comment: I would also add `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l` to avoid the line breaking madness: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365510/how-to-avoid-wrapping-in-bc-output

Answer (score 7):

```
seq -f 4 %g 1 2 99999
```

Gives the data:

```
4/1
4/3 
4/5 
...
4/9999
```

The paste command takes this list and inserts a - between the first two, a + between the second two, etc (and puts it on one line, so):

```
4/1-4/3+4/5-4/7......4/9999
```

Which is an approximation of pi.  The 'bc' program calculates this and prints the value.

Answer (score -1):

For when you *really* need some of those sweet pi digits:

```
sudo apt install pi
pi 10000000
```

Benchmark vs `echo "scale=10000; 4*a(1)" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l` with `time <command>`:

| digits | pi | bc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10^3 |  | 0.24s |
| 10^4 | 6ms | 87s |
| 10^5 | 60ms |  |
| 10^6 | 0.8s |  |
| 10^7 | 14s |  |

The `pi` command is a demo of the CNL C++ arbitrary precision library: https://www.ginac.de/CLN/

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, Lenovo ThinkPad P51.