# Constants in Basic C++ program

Tags: c++

In this basic C++ program why can't you print out the constant Pi?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define Pi 3.1415;

int main() {
cout << Pi << endl;
return 0;
} //main
```

Comment: remove ; from #define Pi 3.1415;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Pi` definition contains a semi-colon, `;`.

Upon substitution, the compiled code is

```
cout <<  3.1415; << endl;
```

When it should be

```
cout <<  3.1415 << endl;
```

---

In other words, do

```
#define Pi 3.1415
```

Without the semi colon.

---

Though, better still is to not use `#define` for things like this.

See for example [How to use the PI constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c) for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Pi` definition is a macro not a constant and it expands to a superfluous `;` in your output statement

```
#define Pi 3.1415; // <<
```

will become

```
cout << 3.1415; << endl;
           // ^
```

and you end up with a compilation error.

To declare a constant correctly in C++, you should write

```
const double Pi = 3.1415;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `;` after `3.1415`. 
The code

`#define Pi 3.1415;`

implies that whenever you use `Pi`, it will be replaced by `3.1415;`. Notice how the semicolon also gets included along with the double. So when you use `cout<<Pi<<endl`, the compiler reads it as `cout<<3.1415;<<endl`, which you can see will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon from macro definition

```
#define PI=3.142
```