# Square root in C++ programming language

Tags: c++

please help. what is the syntax to write the square root of the following √4*3.142*A in c plus plus programming language. A is a variable.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/

Comment: Hi Michael! Welcome to SO! Before asking a question, you need to show us that you've put some effort into finding a solution. What research have you done? Where did it lead you? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c

Comment: @RogueBaneling Or the even better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the reference for the C `sqrt`/`sqrtl`/`sqrtf`. Here's the corresponding page for C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: @zenith And wut?? I've chosen that link consciously.

Comment: Hi Michael!  Always feel free to search StackOverflow or the internet before posting.  Often, you can save yourself a lot of effort and time by doing so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? The question is tagged C++.

Answer (score 4):

you can easily use `sqrt(4*3.142*A)`
 but don't forget to add this first `#include<cmath>`

Answer (score 0):

```
****we have function for sqrt provided in math library.****
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
// √4*3.142*A
    int A =10;
    float result = sqrt(4*3.14*A);
    cout<<result<<endl;
 }
```

**result**==11.2071