# Why is PI not defined by default in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, pi

g++ 5.4.0 under cygwin will successfully compile programs with M_PI with no parameters.

However, with -std=c++11 it will give an error.

This question: [How to use the PI constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c)

implies that older machines might need to define

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
```

But in fact no one should be including math.h, now it should be

```
#include <cmath>
```

What is the standard, what should it be?
On my ubuntu, with a much older g++ 4.8.4 it compiles fine.

It is utterly ridiculous that each programmer should define

```
const double pi = 3.14159265358979;
```

for themselves.

Comment: why it is utterly ridiculous? For a mathematician it may sound utterly ridiculous that you call the value `3.14159265358979` pi. When you cut infinite digits `3` can be just as valid as approximation as any other choice

Comment: pi is intrinsicly defined in the math lib when you do `4*atan(-1)` making the definition of pi redundant and possibly different depending on the way `atan` is computed. and you get ovoïd circles :)

Comment: @tobi303: `double pi = 3` has an error which is _well_ beyond the ULP. Because pi is irrational, there is in fact a unique best approximation.

Comment: @MSalters I should be more careful with making sloppy not too serious comments when you are around :P

Comment: @tobi303: Now you've ruined my weekend, by telling met that you've been putting sloppy comments all over StackOverflow. Can't leave those unchallenged, so that's my next 48 hours wasted :P

Comment: @MSalters dont worry, the rest of the day I was actually seriously working.... but I have a full weekend without plans in front of me