# There are wrong answer when cout the long double value, C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const long double longDoublePI = 3.141592653589793238;
    cout << setw(16) << "longDoublePI = " << setprecision(numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1) << longDoublePI << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But the result output is:

longDoublePI = 3.141592653589793116

Why the answer is wrong?

Comment: Because 3.141592653589793116  is the `double` nearest to 3.141592653589793238.

Comment: Short answer: expecting exact results from floating-point approximations is a surefire recipe for disappointment.

Comment: In what sense is the answer wrong? It's not accurate enough for you? How accurate are you expecting it to be and why?

Comment: But it is long double type, it should be more precise than double.
Moreover, I set the most precision for long double, numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1.

Comment: `longDoublePI` is a `long double` but `n.nnnnn` is a `double` unless you tell the compiler otherwise.

Comment: @Ann A very important rule to understand in both C and C++ is that what you do with a result has no effect on how that result is computed. C++'s type system and promotion rules are complex enough without adding all the possible additional wrinkles that would add.

Comment: Read more about [floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), pay close attention to the *suffixes*.

Comment: The problem is that the type of the literal `3.141592653589793238` is just double; the type of `longDoublePI` doesn't change that.  Try `3.141592653589793238L`.

Comment: I think I got it!

Comment: All of these answers in the comments section. Sigh.

Comment: A must read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: this is not a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken  that question is about the general accuracy issues with FP. This question is about failing to designate the FP literal as being a `long double` by suffixing it with `L`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, although `longDoublePI` is a `long double`, **the literal from which you initialised it is only a `double`**, which does not have as much precision.

You can use this instead:

```
const long double longDoublePI = 3.141592653589793238L;
//                                                   ^
```

Comment: Note that this is a particular trap when using the M_PI macro. You can't append an 'L' to that, so it is always inaccurate to initialise `long double` varable with M_PI or to use M_PI in a `long double` calculation.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, this is platform dependent. The standard (C++14, 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental] para 8) stipulates that long double only has at least as much precision as float. In practice, I would expect it to have the same or more precision than double, at least on desktop/server platforms.

Generally I would use standard macros like M_PI to get well-known constants. I don't know of any standard long double versions, though GNU seems to have M_PIl as a non-standard extension.

Finally, other than M_PI, the standard trick to get pi is to use

4.0L*std::atan(1.0L)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c) for more discussion.

Comment: Meh. See comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1727886/560648