# Converting a mathematical equation into a C++ code

Tags: c++

I have a homework in C++ Intro. and one of it said to convert the following mathematical equation into a C++ code:

```
x = 10π/(a+b) sin3C+ 3(ln a)(tan C)
```

where a,b, and C are user-input and C is in degrees.

I've tried it myself and had end up with this:

```
float x,y,z,a,b,C;

cout<< "Input the a-value: ";
cin>> a;

cout<< "\nInput the b-value: ";
cin>> b;

cout<< "\nInput the C-value: ";
cin>> C;
C = C*3.1416/180;

x = (10*3.1416/a+b)*pow(sin(C),3)+3*log(a)*tan(C);
cout<< "\n The value of x is " << x;
```

I've tried a=5,b=10, and C=15 and the result of x is 1.57606.
I've tried it in a scientific calculator and x became 1.33005.
What could be the problem in my code? Thank you!

*I'm sorry if there's anything wrong with my post structure because it's my first time to post here and English is not my native language*

Comment: Note that you didn't respect the parenthesis in `(a+b)` from the original equation. And I don't see the exponent in the original equation that is implied by the `pow` in your code, but that may be a formatting issue.

Comment: Please take more care when copy-pasting the equation from your homework. Clearly you intended `sin³(C)`, so please ensure that the question reflects that.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I'll take note of that in the future. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(10*3.1416/a+b)
```

is not the same as 10π/(a+b), you meant

```
(10*3.1416/(a+b))
```

Comment: Also note that π is not `3.1416`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c) for what you can do instead.

Comment: Oh wow, I guess you're right. I'm really sorry, such foolish mistake. Thanks you!