# Standard library breaks when changing language standard

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, standards

I have Eclipse C++ and integrated with it a long time ago MinGW. At some moment, I needed C++17's standard library functionality. I did `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect` and changed `Language standard` from *Whitespace* to `ISO C++17 (-std=c++17)`. After that, the constant `M_PI` in `<cmath>` became invalid (isn't defined). This happens with *every* option I choose (except *Whitespace*). I've reinstalled & reintegrated MinGW.

Comment: `M_PI` is not standard. See [How to use the PI constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727881/10077).

Comment: Top answer calls for `M_PI` specifically. Top comment of the second answer is good, though. Another question is whether their version of MinGW supports C++17 properly. If it's relatively current, it likely does, but people love running around with ancient software. Not released to stable yet, but C++20 will have direct support for many mathematical constants, including pi.

Comment: @sweenish GCC 10 has C++20 support. MinGW-w64 versions of GCC 10 for Windows can be found at http://winlibs.com/