# Convert lat, long to x, y on Mollweide

Tags: c++, geo

I have tried to follow the instructions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection) but I get wild results compared to [this](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=54009&x=8.0000000&y=10.0000000) site.

Here is my code.

```
#include <cmath>

double solveNR(double latitude, double epsilon) {
  if (abs(latitude) == M_PI / 2) {
    return latitude;
  }

  double theta = latitude;
  while (true) {
    double nextTheta = theta - (2 * theta * std::sin(2 * theta) - M_PI * std::sin(latitude)) / (2 + 2 * std::cos(2 * theta));
    if (abs(theta - nextTheta) < epsilon) {
      break;
    }
    theta = nextTheta;
  }
  return theta;
}

void convertToXY(double radius, double latitude, double longitude, double* x, double* y) {

  latitude = latitude * M_PI / 180;
  longitude = longitude * M_PI / 180;
  double longitudeZero = 0 * M_PI / 180;
  double theta = solveNR(latitude, 1);

  *x = radius * 2 * sqrt(2) * (longitude - longitudeZero) * std::cos(theta) / M_PI;
  *y = radius * sqrt(2) * std::sin(theta);
}
```

For instance,

180 longitude = 21

90 latitude = 8.1209e+06

assuming a radius of 5742340.81

I found [this](https://github.com/dtutic/proj.4/blob/master/src/PJ_moll.c) resource which seems to calculate the right answer. But I cannot parse how it is different.

Comment: How are you definging PI?  Using your code, and the input of 180 and 90, I get an output of `9.94552e-10` and  `8.1209e+06`.  I defined PI using `#include <math.h>`

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @J'e it's not you but math.h who defined `M_PI`, but that's non-standard. The standard way is [`std::numbers::pi` in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285400/995714)

Comment: Sorry I defined PI as 3.14159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solveNR() function why do you use

```
double nextTheta = theta - (2 * theta * std::sin(2 * theta) - PI * 
std::sin(latitude)) / (2 + 2 * std::cos(2 * theta));
```

instead

```
double nextTheta = theta - (2 * theta + std::sin(2 * theta) - PI * 
std::sin(latitude)) / (2 + 2 * std::cos(2 * theta));
```

Seems like you should use "+" instead "*" (after `2 * theta` in the numerator), to accord with wiki-instructions.

Comment: That definitely helped! I still don't have the exact right answer but thank you!!